# How to print a query string with parameter values when using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm

Is it possible in Hibernate to print generated SQL queries with real values instead of question marks?

How would you suggest to print queries with real values if it is not possible with Hibernate API?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql

Comment: 2024 update - a log of these answers are out of date. If using Spring boot 3 check out the answer from @Erik Pragt.

Answer (score 562, accepted):

You need to enable [logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging) for the the following categories:

- `org.hibernate.SQL`   - set to `debug` to log all SQL DML statements as they are executed
- `org.hibernate.type` - set to `trace` to log all JDBC parameters

So a log4j configuration could look like:

```
# logs the SQL statements
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug 

# Logs the JDBC parameters passed to a query
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

The first is equivalent to `hibernate.show_sql=true` legacy [property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional), the second **prints the bound parameters among other things.**

Another solution (non hibernate based) would be to use a JDBC proxy driver like [P6Spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy).

Comment: This is useful. But this does not show me the real SQL queries.

Comment: @Nicolas that's true, however inmediately after the query it dispays the binded parameters.

Comment: I am using grails 2.4.4 and hibernate 4. Changing log4j configuration did not work for me but p6spy worked!

Comment: Adding the `org.hibernate.type` category to my appender didn't work for me, but adding the `org.hibernate.loader.hql` category instead did work.

Comment: the logging of JDBC params doesn't work in hibernate 4

Comment: You may need to tell Hibernate what logging manager you use (log4j, slf4j), see [how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639997/how-do-you-configure-logging-in-hibernate-4-to-use-slf4j).

Comment: In Hibernate 5 we can use `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder` logger. Enabling logging on `org.hibernate.type` printed too much useless info for me...

Comment: `org.hibernate.type` and `org.hibernate.loader.hql` not work for me to show the parameters

Comment: Where should I put those configurations?

Comment: So, if you already have `hibernate.show_sql=true`, you can skip the first part and just add the `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace`. Works for me

Comment: "Enabling logging on org.hibernate.type printed too much useless info for me..." Me too. TRACE [,] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] found [...] as column [...] System crashed when a varchar(max) column containing a very large text was logged.

Comment: it works for me with: 
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL= DEBUG
\n logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace

Comment: try it: https://www.programmersought.com/article/9068221566/

Comment: Bound parameters aren't being printed with `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace`

Comment: For sl4j using logging.level.org.hibernate.type=true worked for me

Comment: Can you show the output of what it looks like in the log files? people answering this question have been scared to show what it actually looks like in the log.

Comment: [Alan Hay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate/19299769#19299769) shows a solution that prints the SQL as-is in one line.

Comment: Since hibernate 6, `org.hibernate.type` should be replaced by `org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind`. Cf. https://www.muehlencord.de/wordpress/2023/08/30/log-queries-with-parameters-in-hibernate-5-and-6/

Answer (score 107):

If you are using Spring Boot, just config this:

**`application.yml`**

```
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.type: TRACE
```

**`application.properties`**

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

and nothing more.

Your log will be something like this:

```
2020-12-07 | DEBUG | o.h.SQL:127 - insert into Employee (id, name, title, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-12-07 | TRACE | o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder:64 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [001]
2020-12-07 | TRACE | o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder:64 - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [John Smith]
2020-12-07 | TRACE | o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder:52 - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-12-07 | TRACE | o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder:64 - binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [1]
```

Comment: Small addition: With this setup I also get all the results in my log file.
`logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE` only shows the parameters.

Comment: is there any way to get it to just show the binding values in the same line as "insert"???

Comment: Complicated. That log is inside of library :/

Comment: Worked for me after removing `SQL` in `org.hibernate.SQL`.

Comment: in 2024 Hibernate 6.4 I had to change it to

`logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind = trace`, figured it out following the logger back to `JdbcBindingLogging`

Answer (score 88):

Just for convenience, here is the same configuration example for Logback (SLF4J)

```
<appender name="SQLROLLINGFILE">
 <File>/tmp/sql.log</File>
 <rollingPolicy>
  <FileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
 </rollingPolicy>
 <layout>
  <Pattern>%-4date | %msg %n</Pattern>
 </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" additivity="false" >   
 <level value="DEBUG" />    
 <appender-ref ref="SQLROLLINGFILE" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate.type" additivity="false" >
 <level value="TRACE" />
 <appender-ref ref="SQLROLLINGFILE" />
</logger>
```

The output in your sql.log (example) then looks like this:

```
2013-08-30 18:01:15,083 | update stepprovider set created_at=?, lastupdated_at=?, version=?, bundlelocation=?, category_id=?, customer_id=?, description=?, icon_file_id=?, name=?, shareStatus=?, spversion=?, status=?, title=?, type=?, num_used=? where id=?
2013-08-30 18:01:15,084 | binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - 2012-07-11 09:57:32.0
2013-08-30 18:01:15,085 | binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - Fri Aug 30 18:01:15 CEST 2013
2013-08-30 18:01:15,086 | binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] -
2013-08-30 18:01:15,086 | binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - com.mypackage.foo
2013-08-30 18:01:15,087 | binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] -
2013-08-30 18:01:15,087 | binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] -
2013-08-30 18:01:15,087 | binding parameter [7] as [VARCHAR] - TODO
2013-08-30 18:01:15,087 | binding parameter [8] as [VARCHAR] -
2013-08-30 18:01:15,088 | binding parameter [9] as [VARCHAR] - MatchingStep@com.mypackage.foo
2013-08-30 18:01:15,088 | binding parameter [10] as [VARCHAR] - PRIVATE
2013-08-30 18:01:15,088 | binding parameter [11] as [VARCHAR] - 1.0
2013-08-30 18:01:15,088 | binding parameter [12] as [VARCHAR] - 32
2013-08-30 18:01:15,088 | binding parameter [13] as [VARCHAR] - MatchingStep
2013-08-30 18:01:15,089 | binding parameter [14] as [VARCHAR] -
2013-08-30 18:01:15,089 | binding parameter [15] as [INTEGER] - 0
2013-08-30 18:01:15,089 | binding parameter [16] as [VARCHAR] - 053c2e65-5d51-4c09-85f3-2281a1024f64
```

Comment: This is not answering the OPs question.

Comment: How do we get it in the same line instead of the "?"

Answer (score 66):

If you're using **Spring Boot 3** and/or **Hibernate 6**, the following configuration will display the parameter values:

```
# basic log level for all messages
logging.level.org.hibernate=info
# SQL statements and parameters
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=trace
# Statistics and slow queries
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL_SLOW=info
# 2nd Level Cache
logging.level.org.hibernate.cache=debug
```

Answer (score 43):

Change `hibernate.cfg.xml` to:

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

Include log4j and below entries in "log4j.properties":

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE

log4j.appender.hb=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.hb.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Comment: Thanks, has worked for me really well. Those settings will add under the sql query a parameter like `binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [1]`.

Answer (score 28):

Log4JDBC is a nice solution which prints the *exact* SQL going to the database with parameters in place, rather than the most popular answer here which does not do this. One major convenience of this is that you can copy the SQL straight to your DB front-end and execute it as-is.

- http://log4jdbc.sourceforge.net/
- https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc-remix/

The latter also outputs a tabular representation of query results.

Sample Output showing generated SQL with params in place together with result set table from query:

```
5. insert into ENQUIRY_APPLICANT_DETAILS (ID, INCLUDED_IN_QUOTE, APPLICANT_ID, TERRITORY_ID, ENQUIRY_ID, ELIGIBLE_FOR_COVER) values (7, 1, 11, 1, 2, 0) 

10 Oct 2013 16:21:22 4953 [main] INFO  jdbc.resultsettable  - |---|--------|--------|-----------|----------|---------|-------|
10 Oct 2013 16:21:22 4953 [main] INFO  jdbc.resultsettable  - |ID |CREATED |DELETED |CODESET_ID |NAME      |POSITION |PREFIX |
10 Oct 2013 16:21:22 4953 [main] INFO  jdbc.resultsettable  - |---|--------|--------|-----------|----------|---------|-------|
10 Oct 2013 16:21:22 4953 [main] INFO  jdbc.resultsettable  - |2  |null    |null    |1          |Country 2 |1        |60     |
10 Oct 2013 16:21:22 4953 [main] INFO  jdbc.resultsettable  - |---|--------|--------|-----------|----------|---------|-------|
```

---

#### Update 2016

Most recently I have now been using `log4jdbc-log4j2` (https://code.google.com/archive/p/log4jdbc-log4j2/ ) with SLF4j and `logback`. Maven dependencies required for my setup are as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>$logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The driver and DB URLs then look like:

```
database.driver.class=net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy
database.url=jdbc:log4jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db_name #Hsql
#database.url=jdbc:log4jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name
```

My `logback.xml` configuration file looks like the below: this outputs all SQL statements with parameters plus the resultset tables for all queries.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="jdbc.audit" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="jdbc.connection" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="jdbc.sqltiming" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="jdbc.resultset" level="ERROR" />
    
    <!-- UNCOMMENT THE BELOW TO HIDE THE RESULT SET TABLE OUTPUT -->
    <!--<logger name="jdbc.resultsettable" level="ERROR" /> -->

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Finally, I had to create a file named `log4jdbc.log4j2.properties` at the root of the classpath e.g. `src/test/resources` or src/main/resources in a Maven project.  This file has one line:

```
log4jdbc.spylogdelegator.name=net.sf.log4jdbc.log.slf4j.Slf4jSpyLogDelegator
```

The above will depend on your logging library. See the docs at https://code.google.com/archive/p/log4jdbc-log4j2 for more info.

Sample Output:

```
10:44:29.400 [main] DEBUG jdbc.sqlonly -  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
5. select memberrole0_.member_id as member_i2_12_0_, memberrole0_.id as id1_12_0_, memberrole0_.id 
as id1_12_1_, memberrole0_.member_id as member_i2_12_1_, memberrole0_.role_id as role_id3_12_1_, 
role1_.id as id1_17_2_, role1_.name as name2_17_2_ from member_roles memberrole0_ left outer 
join roles role1_ on memberrole0_.role_id=role1_.id where memberrole0_.member_id=104 

10:44:29.402 [main] INFO  jdbc.resultsettable - 
|----------|---|---|----------|--------|---|-----|
|member_id |id |id |member_id |role_id |id |name |
|----------|---|---|----------|--------|---|-----|
|----------|---|---|----------|--------|---|-----|
```

Comment: Actually, the *latter* outputs a tabluar representation of query results ... i.e. one needs log4jdbc-remix for that nice feature.

Comment: This is very cool and also works for spring boot. Also much easier to integrate there. See [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376778/can-log4jdbc-be-used-with-spring-boot/59771403#59771403)

Comment: To avoid adding a library, generally what I do is to put a conditional breakpoint on BasicExtractor#extract method (in hibernate core lib) , example if I am interested in a query on table table_A I do this conditional break point (rs.getStatement().toString().contains("table_A")) and my real SQL query is rs.getStatement().toString()

Answer (score 11):

You can add category lines to log4j.xml:

```
<category name="org.hibernate.type">
    <priority value="TRACE"/>
</category>
```

and add hibernate properties:

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

Answer (score 10):

Add the following to your log4j or logback configuration:

```
org.hibernate.sql=DEBUG
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Comment: The `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder` category doesn't include all parameters, eg enum types.  So if you want everything, you really need `TRACE` for the entire `org.hibernate.type` group.

Comment: Note that org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor logs the result sets. So having large size entry can even crash the apllication when logging to console in Eclipse, and I suppose it is also not ideal for logging into file. That is why I prefer this solution, it works also in Hibernate 3. For those who are interested in enum types, please try out the exact class that logs them when org.hibernate.type=TRACE. Then set org.hibernate.type.xyz.TheClassThatLogsEnumParams=TRACE.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it using the [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy), as I described in [this post](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-log-jdbc-statements/).

Assuming your application expects a `dataSource` bean (e.g. via `@Resource`), this is how you can configure `datasource-proxy`:

```
<bean id="actualDataSource" class="bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource" init-method="init"
  destroy-method="close">
    <property name="className" value="bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.lrc.LrcXADataSource"/>
    <property name="uniqueName" value="actualDataSource"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="0"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="allowLocalTransactions" value="false" />
    <property name="driverProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="user">${jdbc.username}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
            <prop key="url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
            <prop key="driverClassName">${jdbc.driverClassName}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="proxyDataSource" class="net.ttddyy.dsproxy.support.ProxyDataSource">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="testDataSource"/>
    <property name="listener">
        <bean class="net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener.ChainListener">
            <property name="listeners">
                <list>
                    <bean class="net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener.CommonsQueryLoggingListener">
                        <property name="logLevel" value="INFO"/>
                    </bean>
                    <bean class="net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener.DataSourceQueryCountListener"/>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<alias name="proxyDataSource" alias="dataSource"/>
```

Now the Hibernate output vs. datasource-proxy:

```
INFO  [main]: n.t.d.l.CommonsQueryLoggingListener - Name:, Time:1, Num:1, Query:{[select company0_.id as id1_6_, company0_.name as name2_6_ from Company company0_][]}
INFO  [main]: n.t.d.l.CommonsQueryLoggingListener - Name:, Time:0, Num:1, Query:{[insert into WarehouseProductInfo (id, quantity) values (default, ?)][19]}
INFO  [main]: n.t.d.l.CommonsQueryLoggingListener - Name:, Time:0, Num:1, Query:{[insert into Product (id, code, company_id, importer_id, name, version) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)][phoneCode,1,-5,Phone,0]}
```

The `datasource-proxy` queries contain parameter values and you can even add custom JDBC statement interceptors so that you can [catch N+1 query issues right from your integration tests](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-detect-the-n-plus-one-query-problem-during-testing/).

Answer (score 5):

Turn on the `org.hibernate.type` logger to see how the actual parameters are bind to the question marks.

Answer (score 5):

For development with Wildfly (`standalone.xml`), add these loggers:

```
<logger category="org.hibernate.SQL">
   <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
<logger category="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql">
   <level name="TRACE"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using a YAML property:

```yaml
logging.level.org.hibernate:
    SQL: DEBUG
    type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: TRACE
```

Comment: I already have logging:
level: ${env.LOG_LVL:'INFO'} in application.yaml file how to add for hibernate [TRACE] with the existing one.

Answer (score 4):

Logging works but not exactly what you want and I wanted some time ago, but [P6Spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) does work *perfectly*.

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-solution/) is simple tutorial to implement as well. For me it worked like charm.

1. **Download the P6Spy library:** Get [`p6spy-install.jar`](http://www.p6spy.com/)
2. **Extract it:** Extract the `p6spy-install.jar` file, look for `p6spy.jar` and `spy.properties`
3. **Add library dependency:** Add `p6spy.jar` into your project library dependency
4. **Modify P6Spy properties file:** Modify your database configuration file. You need to replace your existing JDBC driver with the P6Spy JDBC driver (`com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver`)

Original is MySQL JDBC driver –(`com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`)

```
<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  <!-- note the difference -->
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myuser</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
</session-factory>
```

Changed it to P6Spy JDBC driver (`com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver`)

```
<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver</property>  <!-- note the difference -->
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myuser</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
</session-factory>
```

5. **Modify P6Spy properties file:** `spy.properties`

Replace the `realdriver` with your existing MySQL JDBC driver

```
realdriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# specifies another driver to use
realdriver2=
# specifies a third driver to use
realdriver3=
```

Change the logfile location in the `logfile` property. All SQL statements will be logged into this file.

Windows:

```
logfile=c:/spy.log
```

UNIX:

```
logfile=/srv/log/spy.log
```

6. **Copy `spy.properties` to project classpath:** Copy `spy.properties` to your project root folder. Make sure your project can locate `spy.properties`, or else a `spy.properties file not found` exception will be thrown.

Comment: This was the easiest path forward for me in my Spring Boot application, where I was trying to log SQL generated from a unit test.  I added a test dependency to Gradle (testCompile 'p6spy:p6spy:3.8.5'), adjusted application.yml to set spring.datasource.url=jdbc:p6spy:h2:mem:testdb and spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver, and then added spy.properties with realdriver=org.h2.Driver and logfile set to my preferred path.  It was easy to extract the complete SQL from the resulting log file.  The only hiccup was that H2 didn't like the generated timestamp format.

Answer (score 4):

```
<!-- A time/date based rolling appender -->
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="logs/system.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="200MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="100" />

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %d{Z} [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="journaldev-hibernate" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="logs/project.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="200MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="50" />

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %d{Z} [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.journaldev.hibernate" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="journaldev-hibernate" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate.type" additivity="false">
    <level value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>

<root>
    <priority value="INFO"></priority>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what worked for me, set below property in the log4j.file:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Hibernate properties settings :

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is correct but logs also all bindings for the result objects.  To prevent this it's possible to create a separate appender and enable filtering. For example:

```
<!-- A time/date based rolling appender -->
<appender name="FILE_HIBERNATE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
    <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/hiber.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="false"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="TRACE"/>
    <!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter">
        <param name="StringToMatch" value="bind" />
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
    </filter>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter">
        <param name="StringToMatch" value="select" />
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
    </filter>  
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
</appender> 

<category name="org.hibernate.type">
  <priority value="TRACE"/>
</category>

<logger name="org.hibernate.type">
   <level value="TRACE"/> 
   <appender-ref ref="FILE_HIBERNATE"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL">
   <level value="TRACE"/> 
   <appender-ref ref="FILE_HIBERNATE"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 3):

I like this for log4j:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=trace
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.engine.query=trace
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=trace
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor=error 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.CollectionType=error
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want Hibernate to print generated SQL queries with real values instead of question marks, add following entries to `hibernate.cfg.xml/hibernate.properties`:

```
show_sql=true
format_sql=true
use_sql_comments=true
```

And add following entries to `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
log4j.appender.hb=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.hb.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Comment: Hey single31 above lines has to be added in your hibernate configuration file then it will definitely work. I always post thing which I have done practically.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is a little variance for the question.
Sometimes, we only need the sql only for debug purposes in runtime.
In that case, there are a more easy way, using debug on editors.

- Put a breakpoint on `org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntityBatch` (or navigate on the stack until there);
- When execution is suspended, look the value of variable `this.sql`

This is for Hibernate 3. I'm not sure that this work on other versions.

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL JDBC driver already provides a convenient feature to meet this requirement. You must at least the have the JAR version greater than or equal to 5.1.6 (e.g. `mysql-connect-jar-5.1.6.jar`)

1. Configure `jdbc.url` to add logger your logger and custom logging:

   ```
   jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://host:port/your_db?logger=com.mysql.jdbc.log.Slf4JLogger&profileSQL=true&profilerEventHandler=com.xxx.CustomLoggingProfilerEventHandler
   ```

It is using `slf4j` logging, if your default logging is `log4j`, you must add `slf4j-api` and `slf4j-log4j12` as dependencies to use `slf4j` logging:

2. Write your custom logging code:

   ```java
   package com.xxx;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.util.Properties;

   import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
   import com.mysql.jdbc.log.Log;

   public class CustomLoggingProfilerEventHandler implements ProfilerEventHandler {
       private Log log;

       public LoggingProfilerEventHandler() {
       }

       public void consumeEvent(ProfilerEvent evt) {
           /**
               * you can only print the sql as his.log.logInfo(evt.getMessage())
               * you can adjust your sql print log level with: DEBUG,INFO
               * you can also handle the message to meet your requirement
               */ 
           this.log.logInfo(evt);
       }

       public void destroy() {
           this.log = null;
       }

       public void init(Connection conn, Properties props) throws SQLException {
           this.log = conn.getLog();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate shows query and their parameter values in different lines.

If you are using `application.properties` in Spring Boot and you can use below highlighted parameter in `application.properties`.

- `org.hibernate.SQL` will show queries:

  ```
  logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
  ```
- `org.hibernate.type` will show all parameter values, which will map with `select`, `insert` and `update` queries.

  ```
  logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
  ```
- `org.hibernate.type.EnumType` will show enum type parameter value:

  ```
  logging.level.org.hibernate.type.EnumType=TRACE
  ```

  Example output:

  ```
  2018-06-14 11:06:28,217 TRACE [main] [EnumType.java : 321] Binding [active] to parameter: [1]
  ```
- `sql.BasicBinder` will show integer, varchar, boolean type parameter value

  ```
  logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
  ```

  Example output:

  ```
  * 2018-06-14 11:28:29,750 TRACE [http-nio-9891-exec-2] [BasicBinder.java : 65] binding parameter [1] as [BOOLEAN] - [true]
  * 2018-06-14 11:28:29,751 TRACE [http-nio-9891-exec-2] [BasicBinder.java : 65] binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [1]
  * 2018-06-14 11:28:29,752 TRACE [http-nio-9891-exec-2] [BasicBinder.java : 65] binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [public]
  ```

Comment: Even this doesn't show the values for _limit_ and _offset_ in queries.

Answer (score 2):

Log4Jdbc plugin would be best for your requirement. It shows following-

```
1. Complete SQL query being hit to the db
2. Parameter values being passed to the query
3. Execution time taken by each query
```

Refer below link to configure Log4Jdbc-

```
https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" 
      value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate.type" additivity="false">
    <level value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Using Hibernate 4 and `slf4j`/`log4j2`, I tried adding the following to my `log4j2.xml` configuration:

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder" level="trace" additivity="false"> 
    <AppenderRef ref="Console"/> 
</Logger> 
<Logger name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType" level="trace" additivity="false"> 
    <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
</Logger>
```

but without success.

I found out through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639997/how-do-you-configure-logging-in-hibernate-4-to-use-slf4j) that the `jboss-logging` framework used by Hibernate needed to be configured in order to log through `slf4j`. I added the following argument to the VM arguments of the application:

```
-Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j
```

And it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using hibernate 3.2.X use this:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=trace
```

instead of this:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

Answer (score 1):

You can log this: `net.sf.hibernate.hql.QueryTranslator`

Output example:

```
2013-10-31 14:56:19,029 DEBUG [net.sf.hibernate.hql.QueryTranslator] HQL: select noti.id, noti.idmicrosite, noti.fcaducidad, noti.fpublicacion, noti.tipo, noti.imagen, noti.visible, trad.titulo, trad.subtitulo, trad.laurl, trad.urlnom, trad.fuente, trad.texto  from org.ibit.rol.sac.micromodel.Noticia noti join noti.traducciones trad where index(trad)='ca' and noti.visible='S' and noti.idmicrosite=985 and noti.tipo=3446       
2013-10-31 14:56:19,029 DEBUG [net.sf.hibernate.hql.QueryTranslator] SQL: select noticia0_.NOT_CODI as x0_0_, noticia0_.NOT_MICCOD as x1_0_, noticia0_.NOT_CADUCA as x2_0_, noticia0_.NOT_PUBLIC as x3_0_, noticia0_.NOT_TIPO as x4_0_, noticia0_.NOT_IMAGEN as x5_0_, noticia0_.NOT_VISIB as x6_0_, traduccion1_.NID_TITULO as x7_0_, traduccion1_.NID_SUBTIT as x8_0_, traduccion1_.NID_URL as x9_0_, traduccion1_.NID_URLNOM as x10_0_, traduccion1_.NID_FUENTE as x11_0_, traduccion1_.NID_TEXTO as x12_0_ from GUS_NOTICS noticia0_ inner join GUS_NOTIDI traduccion1_ on noticia0_.NOT_CODI=traduccion1_.NID_NOTCOD where (traduccion1_.NID_CODIDI='ca' )and(noticia0_.NOT_VISIB='S' )and(noticia0_.NOT_MICCOD=985 )and(noticia0_.NOT_TIPO=3446 )
```

Comment: Hey ... I cant find any examples of this approach.  Could you provide any reference/examples/tutorials.  And is it still same with the latest versions or hibernate/log4j or has it become some org.hibernate.QueryTranslator or something.  Thanks

Comment: Hey ... I tried this, but this does not seem to work with save or update.  I guess it only works for select queries, where translation from hql to sql comes into play

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers here are helpful, but if you're using a Spring application context XML to setup your session factory, setting the log4j SQL level variable only gets you part of the way there, you also have to set the hibernate.show_sql variable in the app context itself to get Hibernate to start actually showing the values.

ApplicationContext.xml has:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
            hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=25
            ... <!-- Other parameter values here -->
            hibernate.show_sql=true
            </value>
 </property>
```

And your log4j file needs

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java:

Transform your query in TypedQuery if it's a CriteriaQuery (javax.persistence).

Then:

query.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString();

Comment: Thanks, It prints the query, but not the parameters that it used, there is a way to print the parameters too?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think its possible to map them like this. I would log them and do the work manually as a workaround ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) or something similar:

None of the above mentioned answers will print SQL with parameters properly, or it is a pain to get it working with them. I achieved this by using [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html), which captures all SQL/commands being send from the application to Oracle/MySQL etc. with the queries.

Comment: Log4JDBC will. See above.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for me is implementing a regular string replacement to replace parameter inputs with parameter values (treating all parameters as string, for simplicity):

```java
String debuggedSql = sql;
// then, for each named parameter
debuggedSql = debuggedSql.replaceAll(":"+key, "'"+value.toString()+"'");
// and finally
System.out.println(debuggedSql);
```

Or something similar for positional parameters (?).

Take care of null values and specific value types like date, if you want a run ready SQL to be logged.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with all of the answers here. None of them actually gave me parameters for the Spring Data JPA query that was being passed an enum as the PK.

For Hibernate 5.3:

```xml
    <!-- silence the noise -->
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl" additivity="false"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.boot.internal" additivity="false"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.engine.internal" additivity="false"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.engine.jdbc" additivity="false"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.engine.transaction" additivity="false"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal" additivity="false"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionEntry" additivity="false"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan" additivity="false"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache" additivity="false"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue" additivity="false"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions" additivity="false"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue" additivity="false"/>
    <Logger name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder" level="trace" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.engine" level="trace" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
```

With `hibernate.format_sql` set to `true` for pretty print, this is a sample of my output:

```
17:00:00,664 [TRACE] Named parameters: {1=DE} [main] org.hibernate.engine.spi.QueryParameters.traceParameters(QueryParameters.java:325) 
17:00:00,671 [DEBUG] 
    select
        countrysub0_.code as code1_23_,
        countrysub0_1_.country_subdivision as country_1_61_ 
    from
        country_subdivision countrysub0_ 
    left outer join
        jurisdiction_country_subdivision countrysub0_1_ 
            on countrysub0_.code=countrysub0_1_.jurisdiction 
    where
        countrysub0_.code=? [main] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:103)
```

I tried simply setting `org.hibernate.engine.spi.QueryParameters` to `trace`, but for some reason the named parameters kept getting silenced, so I silenced everything else that was logging instead. It doesn't seem to log all parameters though, so I still needed the `BasicBinding` log as well.

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure as below:

```
# Hibernate logging options (INFO only shows startup messages)
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO

# Log JDBC bind parameter runtime arguments
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring-boot you can use log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter dependency, which is a fork of org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2 .

In `pom.xml` I used the following dependency:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.integralblue</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

In documentation  it's mentioned that if you just include this dependency SQL logging will not work, we have to specify following property in application.properties

```
logging.level.jdbc.sqlonly=INFO
```

but with

> 2.0.0 version,  All the logging properties are set to info by default . at time of writing this answer the usage count for  2.0.0 is less compared to 1.0.2

So with 2.0.0 even if you don't specify any properties for logging sql following properties are set by default

```
logging.level.jdbc.sqlonly=INFO
logging.level.jdbc.resultset=INFO
logging.level.jdbc.connection=INFO
logging.level.jdbc.resultsettable=INFO
logging.level.jdbc.audit=INFO
logging.level.jdbc.sqltiming=INFO
```

So if you want only SQL queries printed with ? replaced with actual values and avoid  unnecessary log from result set these properties explicitly to

```
logging.level.jdbc.sqlonly=INFO
logging.level.jdbc.resultset=OFF
logging.level.jdbc.connection=OFF
logging.level.jdbc.resultsettable=OFF
logging.level.jdbc.audit=OFF
logging.level.jdbc.sqltiming=OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use Loggers, only insert this into `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: No, this properties wont show any parameter values at all. Notice that the TS explicitly asked for showing them,