# HSQLDB Constraint Violation & SQL Query Log for an HSQLDB in-memory setup

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, junit, hsqldb

We have a setup where we are using an embedded HSQLDB for backing Hibernate/JPA unit tests in java, and we are using the in-memory database mode since we simply want the database thrown away after the test run. My problem is that one of the tests is failing due to a constraint violation and HSQLDB lists the column as SYS_CT_286, and the query that appears in the log is the prepared statement where I cant see what the actual parameter values are (they are replaced by '?'). My questions are:

1- Is there a way in which I can see the actual SQL being executed? (like the mysql query log for example?).

2- What exactly is SYS_CT_286? it is not one of my columns, is it a generated column? is there something obvious that may be wrong with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way in which I can see the actual SQL being executed?

I'm not sure HSQLDB allows to log the SQL statements (like select) being executed but you can use a proxy JDBC driver like [P6Spy](http://www.p6spy.com/) for this (already mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql/2536835#2536835)).

> What exactly is SYS_CT_286?

This is a constraint (and I would bet on a unique constraint).

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB keeps a redo log, which might be useful for debugging what sql has been run, but I'm not sure if it does this for an in-memory db.  If you change your db temporarily to a file-based db named test, the redo log should be named test.log, but it disappears on a clean shutdown.

SYS_CT_286 is most likely a constraint with a system-generated name.  Again, if you make a file-based DB, you might be able to look at it and find out what it's a constraint for.  And if it's a constraint you're defining, you might even be able to change your mapping so it gets a sensible name.  I know you can do this with foreign key constraints anyway.

Comment: The problem is that the database starts and shuts down with the test, so to maintain the log, probably I will need to do some standalone setup. I will try the P6Spy solution first, thanks!

Comment: Sounds sensible to me.  Getting it to use a file-based db might help with diagnosing, but you'd have to hack your tests a bit to do it.

Another thing worth doing is to generate the ddl for your database using the generateSchemaCreationScript(Dialect dialect) method in org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.  If that constraint is generated by hibernate, it should show up there.