# Hibernate: fetching a set of objects in an entity mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I've got an entity Case that has an id CaseId (unfortunately a string due to compability with a legacy system). This id is foreign key in the table Document, and each Case can have many documents (onetomany). I've put the following in my Case entity:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "CaseId", length = 20, nullable = false)
private String caseId;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns ( {
    @JoinColumn(name="caseId", referencedColumnName="CaseId")
} )
private Set<Document> documents;
```

The table for Document contains "CaseId varchar(20) not null". Right now, in the database, all cases have six documents. Yet when I do myCase.documents().size, I only ever get a single document. What should I do to get all the documents?

Cheers

Nik

Comment: Update: What's funny is that first time I access the case, it returns only one document. Next time, it may return two. Third time also perhaps two, and sometimes one. No source changed, no change in the database, nothing that I know how it can explain it. Weird!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping *looks* correct. But it would be interesting to see:

- the `Document` entity (and its `equals`/`hashCode`)
- the SQL performed (see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql/2536835#2536835) to activate SQL logging)

Comment: Dear sir! You are my personal hero today!!! :-) Thanks for the hint of hashCode, I had been thinking of it before, but come away from it. Regenerating it in STS made it tick like it should! :-)

Comment: @niklassaers Glad it's solved. @org.life.java Hmm... what? :)