# Hibernate returning another object

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a query that looks like this

```
Document document = DocDAO.getSession().read(someId);
MyFile file = (MyFile) DAO.getSession()
.createQuery("SELECT file FROM MyFile file WHERE file.document = :document AND file.version = :version")
.setParameter("document", document)
.setParameter("version", version)
.uniqueResult();
```

Now, I should get a file where file.getDocument().getId() == someId, and someId is a BigInteger. But unfortunately, they are not equal. What kind of errors can lead to the queried entity not being the entity I was looking for?

Cheers

Nik

Comment: What database data type is the ID?

Comment: id is a mysql bigint(20)

Comment: This should work. What SQL is performed? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql) to activate SQL logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigInteger is an object, not a primitive. You may need to do `bigInt1.equals(bigInt2)` rather than `bigInt1 == bigInt2`.

EDIT:
Maybe I'm wrong about that. Javadoc says:

> BigInteger provides analogues to all of Java's primitive integer operators

EDIT AGAIN:
If you want to do away with BigInteger, try declaring your JPA entity attribute as a `Long` (or `long` if it is not nullable) and then use the `@Column` annotation to define what the actual database column structure is if necessary. Here is an example of this annotation:

```
@Column(updatable = false, name = "MY_DB_COLUMN", nullable = false, length=12)
private long myEntityAttribute;
```

I don't remember exactly how to use the `length` attribute when the column is numeric. Max number of digits? You can look up the details for `@Column` and experiment until you get it right.

Comment: I haven't used BigInteger, but I'm pretty sure you were right the first time. "Provides analogs" isn't the same thing as "overrides the `==` operator" - which you can't do in Java.

Comment: So, what should I use instead of bigint in MySQL, or BigInteger? I'd love to use a Long, but I don't know what that would map to in MySQL, and my IDs are too long for an integer

Comment: You can override the default mapping from database type to Java entity type. I generated the JPA entities on my current project from Eclipse, and I think BigInteger was the default for non-decimal numeric columns. I just changed them to long (or Long) without modifying the database schema. You'll only have a problem if a database column value exceeds Long.MAX_VALUE, which is very large.

Comment: JPA doesn't perform any `==` nor `equals` comparison (I think that the OP was just trying to explain the expected result).

Comment: I've updated everything to use Longs instead of BigIntegers, but the problem seems to be identical, so perhaps it can be something else that can typically be causing these kind of things?

Comment: @niklassaers It *is* definitely something else, there is no reason why using a `Long` would change anything. Activate the logging of the generated SQL and run it against your database as suggested.

Comment: I agree with Pascal. If the generated SQL isn't right then you'll know that your entity definitions need to change.

Comment: Turns out the problem was in hashcodes. Since the result gave an object with a hashcode of a different object that had the same hashcode.