# How to see queries being fired by hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

How do I see what queries are being fired by hibernate when a hibernate application is running in tomcat?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The fast answer is

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

e.g. as in http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t44119.html

And from the official documentation:

**hibernate.show_sql**

Writes all SQL statements to console. This is an alternative to setting the log category org.hibernate.SQL to debug.
e.g. true | false

**hibernate.format_sql**

Pretty print the SQL in the log and console. e.g. true | false

See this question as well: [Hibernate show real SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql)

Comment: In Tomcat, this would most likely end up in "catalina.out".

Answer (score 5):

Also, if you want to show the value of your parameters you can add

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

to your log4j properties file.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is P6Spy. It intercepts the JDBC driver and logs all transactions.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/