# Junit test failed in Ant, but succesfully finished in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, spring, ant, junit

I am running my junit tests through **Eclipse**, everything works just fine,including inserts bellow.
When I am running  it through **ant** from comand line  I am getting :

**org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:** StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into experiment (id, name, description, journal, user_access) values('1', 'experimentOne', 'first experiment', 'references 1', 'public')]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column count does not match in statement [insert into experiment_metadata (id, name, description, journal_references, user_access).

Can sombody help? I am sure that sql statement is correct.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something wrong with query generation. Query execute is 'insert into experiment', but in exception you're getting 'insert into experiment_metadata'. Can you check if you are not doing any dynamic query updates w/ interceptors or modified jdbc driver. '_metadata' string clearly was updated by your code, not spring's one. Also, what database do you use?

Comment: I am sorry I modified the query before sending it, it is actually insert into  experiment_metadata. It is complaining about wrong number of column...It looks like it loading a wrong schema, even though: hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop, and as II mentioned it works in Eclipse just fine.

Comment: Can you post sample project somewhere into github. Also, what database do you use, can you set debug point and verify that schema was actually dropped.

Comment: Can you , please, explain how I can debug in my junit test case which schema was  exported and was it actually dropped?

Comment: We are using Spring, Hibernate

Comment: For showing sql statements look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql. If that won't help you can monitor which sql queries goes into database - oracle/sql server usually have good toolset for this. What database vendor do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Answer: I figured it out. We had a jar with old classes, that reflected an old schema in our classpath.
That jar was included in ant, and not included in Eclipse.

Regarding how to export a schema:
LocalSessionFactoryBean localfactory1 = (LocalSessionFactoryBean)this.getApplicationContext().getBean("&readOnlySessionFactory");

```
    String customImportFile = "customImportFile.txt";
    System.err.println("Performing schema export with custom import file: '"
            + customImportFile + "'.");
    System.err.println("------JdbcTemplate" + jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());


    try {
    SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport(localfactory1.getConfiguration(), localfactory1.getDataSource().getConnection());
    export.setOutputFile(customImportFile);
    export.create(false, true);
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
```