# SQL Injection through Hibernate-Criteria & Session.save(object)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

To avoid sql injections, normally *Positional parameters* and *named parameters* can be used in HQL as it demos [here](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-hibernate) and stackoverflow also has samples. I want to know which steps can be taken when `Criteria` is used.Any help with sample codes or useful links please.

**Edit**
Also when we save a object then ? let's say,the object may have a String variable and some one can assign a vulnerable sql query to it.

```
 myObject.setName(somevulnerablesql); session.save(myObject);
```

In that case, should we have to check user input seperately before assigning to the object? or any other steps to avoid such sql injections ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite sure that the Criteria-Object will create safe HSQL.

You have to be careful with the [Expression](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Expression.html) object. You may create a SQL-injection there.
But take a look at the generated SQL: [Hibernate show real SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql)

**edit:**
Unless there is a huge bug in Hibernate, you don't have to make sure, that your `String`s are escaped before you save them. Hibernate works with prepared statements. So there is no string concatenation and no SQL-injection with the Hibernate-session.

You may have to escape the output however after reading it with Hibernate. For example:
You have a Entity User

```
class User{
    String name;
}
```

And you call the user "' or 1=1;DROP DATABASE user;--" That string will be stored within the database.
If you query the User with a Criterion object, you will find him (withou dropping the databse). If you query the User with the Expression object, you may drop the database (if you concenate Strings).

If you output the user's name to HTML you have to escape the output. Otherwise an user with a name `"/><script>evilJavascript()</script>` will be bad for your application.

**edit 2:**
take a look here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 3):

Criteria don't allow you to write vulnerable SQL/HQL yourself thus there shouldn't be any problem with SQL injection (unless there's a bug in Hibernate itself).

*Edit*:

As @ckuetbach pointed out, Criteria actually allows you to write SQL using `Expression.sql(String sql)`or `Restrictions.sqlRestriction(String)`.

Comment: That not complete correct I think: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Expression.html

Comment: @ ckuetbach.Thanks. Would you explain more please with some code snip?

Comment: @ckuetbach agreed, I wasn't aware of that. I'll update my answer.