# Hibernate and String primary key, case sensed load

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a tlogin table in my DB which has got a primary key of `String` type, called **Login**. This key is not generated by Hibernate authomatically, as it is assigned by the application. Here it is the mapping:

```
<id name="_Login" column="Login" unsaved-value="null">
    <generator class="assigned" />
</id>
```

My problem comes when user logs in the application. Hibernate `get` and `load` methods seem to return an object with the key that user has typed into the log in form. I'm trying the following code:

```
@Override
public CLogin loadLogin(String userName) throws AccessException {
    try {
        Session sesion = this._dao.init();
        CLogin login = (CLogin) sesion.get(CLogin.class, userName);
        return login;
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        throw new AccessException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Here for example even the username is stored as **example@hotmail.com** in the DB, if the end user logs with **EXAMPLE@hotmail.com**, it will retrieve the object from the DB, but with **EXAMPLE@hotmail.com** key. I want to permit the user access the app, but I want to get his username as it is stored in the DB.

Do I have to implement a criteria for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieved to solve it using an Hibernate Criteria. I use an `ilike` restriction which is an insensitive type of **like**, in addition to `MatchMode.Exact`, which allows to filter only the exact matches.

That's how it works:

```
public CLogin loadLogin(String userName) throws AccessException {
        try {
            Session sesion = this._dao.init();
            CLogin login = (CLogin) sesion.createCriteria(CLogin.class).add(
                    Restrictions.ilike("_Login", userName.toLowerCase(), MatchMode.EXACT))
                    .uniqueResult();
            if (login == null) {
                throw new AccessException("User does not exist");
            }
            return login;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new AccessException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm also torubling into this step. I fixed it by using namedQuery, but i dont want to write the custom method to get the user info or criteriaQuery . I want to know the reason why the default find() or get() method wont works in this. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally go for (as a namedQuery)

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE LOWER(`Login`) = LOWER("EXAMPLE@hotmail.com")
```

but there are other ways.

See
[MySQL case insensitive select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936967/mysql-case-insensitive-select)

Comment: If I have to do that, I would try as an HQL query in order of SQL, to [avoid SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122894/sql-injection-through-hibernate-criteria-session-saveobject).

Comment: Sorry I could not tell if you were using JPA or not, but if so then I find that NamedQueries or PreparedStatements are a lot clean, and of course avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: Yeah, being the question about Hibernate itself, of course I use JPA access. Look at the final solution I achieved. Thanks anyway.