# Hibernate log4j not recognizing log4j.properties

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, log4j, slf4j

I have a hibernate  standard java application (not a webapp).  Logging already works by default.  I would like to see the parameters passed in the sql queries.  I have researched that in order to that I need to enable logging.  It seems as if hibernate uses slf4j.  I have downloaded that jar and its accompanying slf4j-log4j jar.  I have added these jars to the classpath.  I have also added a log4j.properties to the root of the eclipse project.

I can't seem to have the project recognize that it needs to use slf4j and its properties file.

Do I need to add a reference in my hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: AFAIK i dont think you need to mention reference in hibernate.cfg or web.xml. I ran a Spring-mvc hibernate app and used slf4j for logging version 1.4.2. Just try changing the version which might help. Do you want to see something like this?[Hibernate: select contact0_.account as account0_, contact0_.cycle_date as cycle2_0_, contact0_.letter_code as letter3_0_, contact0_.status as status0_ from "Accounts" contact0_]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the property `hibernate.show_sql` set to `true`.

`format_sql` set to true will make the SQL be formatted a bit more pretty.

You may also need to log on TRACE level.

For more details have a look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-display-generated-sql-to-console-show_sql-format_sql-and-use_sql_comments/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql).