# Hibernate shows question marks in SQL query

Tags: java, hibernate

How do I see the actual value in query instead of questions marks? 
Now, I am seeing

```
Hibernate: inser into TABEL (ID, FORMAT, SIZE) values (?,?,?)
```

I want to see the real values being used instead of the question marks.

I set this in my hibernate config file and turned on the debug flag.

```
<property name="show_sql"> true </property>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why did you misspell `inser`(t)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hibernate uses prepared statements so you can't see the full SQL. You can set the log level for `org.hibernate.type` to `trace` to see the values bound to the parameters.

#### Reference

- Hibernate 3.5 Core Documentation

  - [3.5. Logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging)
- Hibernate 4.1 Core Documentation

  - [4.1. Logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-logging)

(As mentioned in/see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2536835/643141)).

Comment: Can you please include a reference for this?

Comment: @Jolley71717 Sure, I added some.

Answer (score -1):

Use Log4j or Logback to enable and set `javax.sql` to `DEBUG`:

```xml
<logger name="java.sql" level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> <!-- or your own appender -->
</logger>
```

Comment: This is not a solution for Hibernate. Spring Actuator shows no loggers with the names `javax.sql` or `java.sql`.