# P6SpyDriver cannot be cast to javax.sql.XADataSource exception while trying to configure P6Spy 2.0 with xa-datasource using Jboss AS 7 and potgres

Tags: jpa-2.0, jboss7.x, p6spy

P6spy v2 has a support for xa datasources - [P6spy on github](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy)

In my jboss AS 7 standalone-full-ha.xml, i have the following datasource configurations.

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MyDS" pool-name="v" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="false">
                <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
                    localhost
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="PortNumber">
                    5432
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">
                    MyDB
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <driver>p6spy</driver>
                <xa-pool>
                    <min-pool-size>50</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>150</max-pool-size>
                    <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                    <interleaving>false</interleaving>
                    <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>
                    <wrap-xa-resource>false</wrap-xa-resource>
                </xa-pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                    <password>postgres</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                </validation>
                <statement>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </xa-datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="p6spy" module="com.p6spy">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

After that, i put the p6spy-2.0.1.jar in jboss\modules\com\p6spy\main folder and also defined the module.xml file. Also, i put the spy.properties file alongwith the P6spy.jar and in that added the line to enable postgres driver

```
realdriver=org.postgresql.Driver
```

With all these settings, when i start my server, i get the following exception.

```
    Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:447)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:385)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:761)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:343)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:397)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:365)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:329)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:368)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:67) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:253) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:119) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2270) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2266) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1735) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver cannot be cast to javax.sql.XADataSource
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXADataSource(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:553)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:430)
    ... 30 more
```

At this step i am clueless as to how should i make it work.

**Edit:**
As per quintonm's reply, i used com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6ConnectionPoolDataSource class which implements XADatasource. But now i am getting the following exception.

```
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not find accessor on XADataSource: 
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXADataSource(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:629)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:430)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6ConnectionPoolDataSource.setDatabaseName(java.lang.String)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1655) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXADataSource(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:597)
```

Also, following the generic instructions stated in P6spy's documentation, i used the 'RealDataSource' property in xa-datasource-properties but it then says no such property exist.

Answer (score 4):

The problem that you are currently facing is that JBoss is expecting you to use a class that implements the Datasource interface in xa-datasource-class.  For the P6Spy driver definition, you are using P6SpyDriver which implements java.sql.Driver.  Instead of using P6SpyDriver, you want to use com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6ConnectionPoolDataSource.

P6Spy's support for DataSource implementations in JNDI is a little different than using a Driver class.  Instead of modifying the JDBC URL, you must setup a second JDNI DataSource.  The one that the application connects to will be the P6Spy DataSource.  That DataSource will be a proxy to the real data source.  The instructions for setting this up are be found [here](http://p6spy.github.io/p6spy/2.0/install.html#generic).

Note: The instructions say that you should use P6DataSource.  However, since you need XA support, you will need to use P6ConnectionPoolDataSource.

For a better understanding of how this works, you can take a look at the test for XADataSources - [XADataSourceTest](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy/blob/master/src/test/java/com/p6spy/engine/spy/XADataSourceTest.java)

If you have any problems getting this to work, just post a message to p6spy-users@googlegroups.com or enter an [issue](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy/issues)

Comment: Sorry i was busy in some other issue so i had to leave this one for a while. I updated my question after implementing the things you suggested. You were right about the P6ConnectionPoolDataSource class. This was not listed in the documentation anywhere. Can you please help me with these new problems i am facing now ?

Answer (score 2):

well, after the update of the question, your config should look like this. Didn't give it a test try, but in general, you need to proxy your existing one (postgres one) via p6spy:

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MyDSReal" pool-name="v" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="false">
            <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
                localhost
            </xa-datasource-property>
            <xa-datasource-property name="PortNumber">
                5432
            </xa-datasource-property>
            <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">
                MyDB
            </xa-datasource-property>
            <driver>postgresql</driver>
            <xa-pool>
                <min-pool-size>50</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>150</max-pool-size>
                <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                <interleaving>false</interleaving>
                <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>
                <wrap-xa-resource>false</wrap-xa-resource>
            </xa-pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                <password>postgres</password>
            </security>
            <validation>
                <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                <background-validation>false</background-validation>
            </validation>
            <statement>
                <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
            </statement>
        </xa-datasource>
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MyDS" pool-name="v" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="false">
            <driver>p6spy</driver>
            <xa-pool>
                <min-pool-size>50</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>150</max-pool-size>
                <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                <interleaving>false</interleaving>
                <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>
                <wrap-xa-resource>false</wrap-xa-resource>
            </xa-pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                <password>postgres</password>
            </security>
            <validation>
                <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                <background-validation>false</background-validation>
            </validation>
            <statement>
                <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
            </statement>
        </xa-datasource>

        <drivers>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
            <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
            <driver name="p6spy" module="com.p6spy">
                <xa-datasource-class>com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6ConnectionPoolDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
```

Moreover I think you don't need spy.properties file if you're OK with default config. As RealDriver property would be needed if going the driver way (not the datasource one as you do now).

**UPDATE**:

removed section reported as problematic:

```
            <xa-datasource-property name="RealDataSource">
                java:jboss/datasources/MyDSReal
            </xa-datasource-property>
```

if that is a problem in the DS config => let's configure it in a different way, you can go for any of available:

- System properties
- Environment variables or
- spy.properties

where you need to set:

```
realdatasource=java:jboss/datasources/MyDSReal
```

**UPDATE 2**:

I gave it a test try and it seems p6spy doesn't support the XA Datasources for the JBoss / Wildfly (yet). For more details, see the official docs: http://p6spy.github.io/p6spy/2.0/install.html

Comment: As i mentioned in my update, the realdatasource property is giving me problem when i tried this way. The exact exception i get with this is : Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: realdatasource type not supported: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource@6c307c16

Comment: Now it is giving me the same exception again - 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6ConnectionPoolDataSource.setDatabaseName(java.lang.String)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1655) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
 at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXADataSource(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:597)

Comment: OK, let me give it a test try and come back to you