# how to see executed hql as sql query in console in grails application

Tags: hibernate, grails

i want to see executed hql in my grails app as sql query in console. like in hibernate we can set this in config file. like

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you have to do.

First, in your `Datasource.groovy` you have to enable logging of SQL:

```
dataSource {
   dbCreate = ...
   url = ...
   ...
   logSql = true
}
```

Secondly, you have to enable the log4j settings in your `Config.groovy`:

```
log4j = {
   ...
   debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'
   trace 'org.hibernate.type'
}
```

With both of these changes in place you will see your SQL/HQL statements being logged.

Comment: i am facing this problem, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql], can i set up http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-solution/ in grails

Comment: That's a different question than the one you have posted here. I would recommend you post a new question asking how to setup P6Spy with Grails.