# show the full query using SQLQuery

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

how to show the full string of a query using [SQLQuery](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#getQueryString%28%29). I tried to use `getQueryString()`
but it doesn't show the parameter values in the returned string.

any idea how to display the full query that will be executed on the MySQL DB server?

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
"select * from stock s where s.stock_code = :stockCode")
.addEntity(Stock.class)
.setParameter("stockCode", "7277");

query.getQueryString(); 
// this will return "select * from stock s where s.stock_code = :stockCode" 
// and I need  "select * from stock s where s.stock_code = 7277"
```

Comment: the code snippet has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable logging of the following categories (using a log4j.properties file here):

```
 log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
 log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Refer this :

- [Hibernate show real SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql)
- [How to print a query string with parameter values when using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values)