# Hibernate query logging : need current timestamp

Tags: java, hibernate

In hibernate configuration I have mentioned show_sql=true.

In the logs I can see that queries are printing which is executed by hibernate.

Like below

`Hibernate : <insert query>
Hibernate : <select query>`

I want to print the current timestamp as well along with query. Like

`<current time > Hibernate : <insert query>
<current time >  Hibernate : <select query>`

I am using Hibernate 4.
I have used `hibernate.generate_statistics=true` but this does not give time for insertion. Moreover, I just need current time.

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql) helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `show_sql=true` option only sets up writing to the system console, it is not a true logger, so you cannot configure it. If you want to get meaningful logging from Hibernate you should configure a logging framework, and use it to control the logging of Hibernate.

I have used the following logging frameworks already, so I can tell you, that these are working well with Hibernate: *log4j*, *slf4j*, *logback*, *log4j2*.

---

#### Using log4j as a logger

For example, this line in a `log4j.properties` file configures *log4j* to keep the same info, which is put out with `show_sql=true`:

```
log4j.category.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

But in this case you *can* configure the output. In my case, the format is defined in the `console` appender:

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %F:%L - %m%n
```

This way, the output is:

```
<current time> DEBUG SqlStatementLogger.java:104 - <insert query>
```

---

#### A complete `log4j.properties` file

For the sake of completeness, I have included my configuration file:

```
# root logger
 log4j.rootLogger = INFO, stdout

# category filters
log4j.category.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE

# appenders
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %F:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used log4j.category.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate maintains statistics on which objects were queried, and how often

– Enable statistics in the configuration file

```
• hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

**Hibernate Interfaces**

– Statistics for global information

– EntityStatistics for info on Object Type

– QueryStatistics for SQL and HQL queries

I think you require logging for timestamp not stats, but you can use any of the below options as per your requirements.

1. You can use log4jdbc JDBC proxy driver for logging SQL and other interesting information.
2. You can use slf4j-api.jar in your classpath together with the jar file for your preferred binding - slf4j-log4j12.jar

To use Log4j you will also need to place a log4j.properties file in your classpath. An example properties file is distributed with Hibernate in the src/ directory.

**Hibernate Log Categories**

org.hibernate.SQL               - 
Log all SQL DML statements as they are executed

org.hibernate.type -              Log all JDBC parameters

org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl -      Log all SQL DDL statements as they are executed

org.hibernate.pretty  -          Log the state of all entities (max 20 entities) associated with the session at flush time

org.hibernate -                    Log everything. This is a lot of information but it is useful for troubleshooting

with Hibernate, you should almost always work with debug enabled for the category org.hibernate.SQL, or, alternatively, the property hibernate.show_sql enabled

```
<attribute name="ShowSqlEnabled">true</attribute>
```

3. With enabling Statistics , for example you can get total no of counts for a particular entity class cat stats. (How many times insert, update or delete called) like below:

`EntityStatistics entityStats =
  stats.getEntityStatistics( Cat.class.getName() );`

`long changes =
        entityStats.getInsertCount()
        + entityStats.getUpdateCount()
        + entityStats.getDeleteCount();`

`log.info(Cat.class.getName() + " changed " + changes + "times"  );`

4. `String hql = "from POJO as POJO where to_date(to_char(POJO.tradeDate, 'DD-MON-YY'), 'DD-MON-YY') = :date"; 
   Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql); 
   query.setParameter("date", date);

`
Please check Hibernate Documentation for more details.