# Hibernate show sql logs coming without time stamp format in logback

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, logback

Iam using hibernate with jpa. When i enabled show sql for hibernate to log the generated sql from hibernate, it is generating without time stamp. Where as all other logs from hibernate is coming as expected. Does the printing of hibernate sql log is done with sysout. How I can set my formatting with this sql log.
I have added logback.xml as required, none of the options work for this sql logs.

Following shows the log extract

```
2019-02-11 16:08:39,629 TRACE [http-nio-8099-exec-2] org.
Hibernate: SELECT ID id, TTOKEN aToken, RTOKEN rToken,ATI
2019-02-11 16:08:39,696 TRACE [http-nio-8099-exec-2] org.
2019-02-11 16:08:39,697 TRACE [http-nio-8099-exec-2] org.
2019-02-11 16:08:39,697 TRACE [http-nio-8099-exec-2] org.
```

Actual result should have the dates shown for sql logs also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate query logging : need current timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556851/hibernate-query-logging-need-current-timestamp)

Comment: I need to resolve this in Logback