# Oracle table naming causes issues when inserting data

Tags: oracle, insert

In Oracle 12c, I had a table named "CONTAINERS" and the following query was failing to insert data.

```
insert  into CONTAINERS (ID,CONTAINER_NAME, HIERARCHY_SUB_TYPES_ID, HIERARCHY_TYPES_ID, SEGMENT_ID, SUB_SEGMENT_ID, USERS_ID_HIERARCHY_OWNER) 
    values  (44,'ContainerName', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Error:

> Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 28 Error report - SQL Error:
>   ORA-02000: missing ) keyword
>   02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"

But this worked successfully

```
insert  into CONTAINERS    values  (3,'ContainerName', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

I had to rename the table from "CONTAINERS" to "CONTAINER" for everything to work normally.

Can someone explain why I got this behavior?

DDL:

```
  CREATE TABLE "RELANDHIER"."CONTAINERS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "CONTAINER_NAME" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "USERS_ID_HIERARCHY_OWNER" NUMBER, 
    "SEGMENT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "SUB_SEGMENT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "HIERARCHY_TYPES_ID" NUMBER, 
    "HIERARCHY_SUB_TYPES_ID" NUMBER
   )
```

Comment: can you post the CREATE TABLE statement

Comment: First insert mentions 8 columns and you only have 7 values. You must specify 8 values, default values won't work here. Second insert DOES NOT specify columns and works. The table MUST have a default value for one of the columns which gets in play in the second insert.

Comment: @davegreen100 Just did.

Comment: @MarcoPolo First insert has 7 columns not 8. Please check the statement again.

Comment: Still, it's a default value problem I am sure. Post a "Describe" or "Create Table" for the table.

Comment: @MarcoPolo Please see the create table SQL in the question. You will see there is no default value specified. And how do you explain why it works when the name changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"CONTAINERS" seems to be a "reserved name". Here is my test case derived from yours :

```
drop table "DEMO"."CONTAINERS";

CREATE TABLE "DEMO"."CONTAINERS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "CONTAINER_NAME" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "USERS_ID_HIERARCHY_OWNER" NUMBER, 
    "SEGMENT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "SUB_SEGMENT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "HIERARCHY_TYPES_ID" NUMBER, 
    "HIERARCHY_SUB_TYPES_ID" NUMBER
   );

insert into CONTAINERS (ID,CONTAINER_NAME, HIERARCHY_SUB_TYPES_ID, HIERARCHY_TYPES_ID, SEGMENT_ID, SUB_SEGMENT_ID, USERS_ID_HIERARCHY_OWNER) 
    values  (44,'ContainerName', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
insert into "DEMO".CONTAINERS (ID,CONTAINER_NAME, HIERARCHY_SUB_TYPES_ID, HIERARCHY_TYPES_ID, SEGMENT_ID, SUB_SEGMENT_ID, USERS_ID_HIERARCHY_OWNER) 
    values  (44,'ContainerName', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

INSERT only works if I prefix the owner schema to it.

Execution gives :

```
Table dropped.


Table created.

insert into CONTAINERS (ID,CONTAINER_NAME, HIERARCHY_SUB_TYPES_ID, HIERARCHY_TYPES_ID, SEGMENT_ID, SUB_SEGMENT_ID, USERS_ID_HIERARCHY_OWNER)
                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02000: missing ) keyword



1 row created.
```

Check this link to [Oracle 12c new features](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12102.htm#NEWFT507)

Comment: Your answer makes senses. I think Oracle needs to updates it's documention for Oracle SQL Reserved Words. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621

Comment: I think just quoting your table name would also resolve the issue. i.e. insert into "CONTAINERS"...

Comment: The problem was that this query was being generated by Hibernate. Not much control of the output.

Comment: It all comes down to good modeling standards. That's why our modeling standards adds an application prefix to all our tables. For example, in our ERP, all our tables are prefixed with "ERP_". This prevents any problems with reserved words. We have tables called "ERP_DATES" and in your case, the table would be named "ERP_CONTAINERS".