# JPQL query not working (possibly because of 'member of')

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.3

If i run the following query:

```
... AND :user MEMBER OF c.owners AND ...
```

it works fine, but if I add the following condition to it like

`...AND ( :user MEMBER OF c.owners 
         OR ( :user MEMBER OF c.department.members AND c.confidential = false ) 
        ) AND ...`

It doesn't give back the result i want (like the previous query). Any idea why?

EDIT

Here are the relevant part of the generated query (the whole query is the same but these parts)

With this I get back the records I want

`and (
    ? in (
        select
            owners1_.owner_id 
        from
            contract_owner owners1_ 
        where
            contract0_.id=owners1_.contract_id
    )
)`

With this i din't get is back

`and (
    ? in (
        select
            owners1_.owner_id 
        from
            contract_owner owners1_ 
        where
            contract0_.id=owners1_.contract_id
    ) 
    or (
        ? in (
            select
                sysuser3_.sysuser_id 
            from
                department_sysuser sysuser3_ 
            where
                department2_.id=sysuser3_.department_id
        )
    ) 
    and contract0_.confidential=0
)`

EDIT2:

In the first snippet i get back 1 record (dev data only, in prod it would be more), and in the second part i want to get back the same record, but it doesn't give it back.

The user is the owner of the contract.

Comment: Please enable [sql logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql/2536835#2536835) and post the generated query.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Added the generated queries

Comment: Is the second snippet what you get back (in the second case) or what you want to get back?  If it's what you want, please post what you do get.

Comment: @WPrecht-AB3RY answered your question in 'EDIT2'

Comment: Assuming the second snippet is cut and paste of what you are generating, it looks like the final AND clause (and contract0_.confidential=0) is on the wrong side of the enclosing param of the OR.  So you might seed the JPA with more params to force the generator to group them the way you want.