# How to see the schema sql (DDL) in spring boot?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

How can I see the DDL SQL generated by Hibernate for building the schema from the JPA mappings? I am using the embedded HSQL db.

I tried the following and none of them worked in Spring-Boot 1.3.5.RELEASE.

- Adding the following to application.properties file

  - debug=true
  - spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
- Set org.hibernate.SQL level to debug in logback.xml
- Steps listed at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Those only show me the sql issued by Hibernate for queries. I am looking for the DDL schema sql issued by Hibernate due the following property:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql) SO question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, but they are the same as above. They only show the queries, not DDL issued by Hibernate when the app boots up.

Comment: the show-sql only shows the DMLs, you will need to add  `debug=true` toapplication.properties to see the DDLs

Comment: @Shibashis I tried `debug=true` as mentioned in my posting already. That still didn't show the DDLs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try with this property and value:

```
javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
```

Do not forget to also set this property:

```
javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=my-schema.sql
```

From the [JPA 2.1 Specifiation](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html),  page 370:

> `javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action`
>
> The **javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action** property specifies
>   which scripts are to be generated by the persistence provider. The
>   values for this property are `none`, `create`, `drop-and-create`, `drop`. A
>   script will only be generated if the script target is specified. If
>   this property is not specified, it is assumed that script generation
>   is not needed or will

In Spring Boot you can define those two properties in your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=build/my-schema.sql
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
```

Here is a blog post about JPA schema generation with further information about these and other properties:
http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/standardized-schema-generation-data-loading-jpa-2-1/

Comment: Hint: This disables the actual schema generation. If you want to create the schema.sql script AND want hibernate to create the schema in the actual DB you must add `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action=create`

Comment: Article which goes into more details about this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-generate-db-schema