# how to convert this HQL to SQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

```
from EmployerCharges r1 where r1.routingCode.routingCode = ? and employer.employerId=?
```

where the following are the pojo classes

```
<class name="com.greytip.wps.model.EmployerCharges"  table="emp_RoutingCode_Charges"  lazy="false">

    <id name="id" type="int" unsaved-value="0" >
        <generator class="native">
            <param name="sequence">emp_RoutingCode_id_seq</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name ="employer" class = "com.greytip.wps.model.Employer"/>
    <many-to-one name ="routingCode" class = "com.greytip.wps.model.RoutingCode"/>
    <property name="charges"/>
</class>
```

//----------------------------------------

hibernate-mapping package="com.greytip.wps.model">

```
<class name="com.greytip.wps.model.Employer"  table="wps_employer"  lazy="false">

    <id name="id" type="int" unsaved-value="0" >
        <generator class="native">
            <param name="sequence">wps_employer_id_seq</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="employerId"/>
    <property name="name"/>
    <property name="contactPerson"/>
    <property name="address"/>
    <property name="bankAcNo"/>
    <property name="email"/>
    <property name="licenseNo"/>
    <property name="licenseExpiryDate"/>
    <property name="active"/>
    <many-to-one name ="emirateCode"/>
    <many-to-one name ="economicActivity"/>
    <many-to-one name ="wpsQueue"/>
    <property name="schemaCreated"/>
    <property name="code"/>
    <many-to-one name ="branch"/>
    <property name="bankCharges"/>
    <property name="contactNo"/>
    <many-to-one name="relationshipManager"/>
    <many-to-one name ="employerGroup"/>
    <property name="hpsEmployerReference"></property>
    <property name="chargeReprocessing"></property>
    <property name="restrictAccess"></property>
    <property name="bankChargesPerFile"></property>
    <property name="enableSalaryCardRequest"></property>
    <property name="salaryCardCharges"/>
    <property name="ftsBankChargesPerFile"/>
    <property name="ftsIntBankChargesPerRecord"/>
    <property name="ftsExtBankChargesPerRecord"/>
    <property name="ftsExtBankChargesPerBank"/>
    <property name="ftsIntBankChargesPerBank"/>
    <property name="signature"/>
    <property name="scReissueCharges"></property>
    <property name="scActivateCharges"></property>
    <property name="scCancelCharges"></property>
    <property name="scReIssuePinCharges"></property>
    <many-to-one name ="employerWorkflow"/>
    <many-to-one name ="employerCategory"/>
    <property name="poBox"></property>
    <property name="bankChargesPerBank"></property>
    <property name="bankChargesPerMonth"></property>
    <property name="defaultCharges"></property>
    <property name="isDeleted"></property>
    <property name="monthlyCharges"></property>
    <property name="appliedCharge"></property>
</class>
```

//-----------------------------------------------

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.greytip.wps.model">

<class name="com.greytip.wps.model.RoutingCode"  table="wps_routingCode"  lazy="false">

    <id name="id" type="int" unsaved-value="0" >
        <generator class="native">
            <param name="sequence">wps_routingCode_id_seq</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="bankCode"/>
    <property name="bankName"/>
    <property name="routingCode"/>
    <property name="branchName"/>
</class>
```

Please tell me how to convert the hql to sql... Thank you..

Comment: Which queries you've tried? Which database is that? Mysql? MS Sql? Oracle? H2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable show sql and format sql parameters in hibernate configuration and you can see the queries being fired in the log file.

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

For more information see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2536829/3503187)

Comment: Hi Ivan,i'm using SQL server 2008 R2 mode.. Thanks for your cooperation in helping me out..