# How to log the sql query generated behind the scene from querydsl using mysemma

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, mysema

Any optimal way to show sql queries which are generated automatically while using querydsl of mysemma, so that these sql queries can be viewed easily and debugging of sql query becomes easy while working on querydsl.

For Example : from(qCustomer).where(qCustomer.custId.eq("1"));

I need to know the sql generated behind the scene and want to log so that I can debug my applications easily.

Comment: Have you tried to use hibernate configuration properties? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql

Comment: Yes Dmitry I have this property configured to true, but then also I am not able to see the sql generated. I am hoping if there is any way at java side or any property at mysemma querydsl side.

Comment: There could be an issue with logger level. Please, have a look at the logger configuration on the link.

Answer (score 13):

Spring boot users, add below to `application.properties` or equivalent yaml file to enable QueryDsl logs.

```
logging.level.com.querydsl.sql=DEBUG
```

Reference - [AbstractSQLQuery's logQuery()](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.2/apidocs/com/querydsl/sql/AbstractSQLQuery.html#logQuery-java.lang.String-java.util.Collection-)

Comment: I use JPA, so need to config `logging.level.com.querydsl.jpa=DEBUG`.

Answer (score 5):

Please add following setting in your application.properties file and check.

**spring.jpa.show-sql=true**

I am seeing the generated SQL using above setting. 
FYI, I am using Spring Data JPA and QueryDSL 4.1.3

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to do it in the code, by

```
String theSqlStr = theDslQuery.getSQL().getSQL();
```

you will get the generated sql