# OptimisticLockException when using JPA merge()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a rest application where one of the resources can be updated. Below are two methods responsible for achieving this task:

1. *updateWithRelatedEntities(String, Store)*: receives id and new object Store which was constructed by deserializing PUT request entity, sets the version (used for optimistic locking) on new object and calls update in a transaction.

   ```
   public Store updateWithRelatedEntities(String id, Store newStore) {
       Store existingStore = this.get(id);

       newStore.setVersion(existingStore.getVersion());

       em.getTransaction().begin();
       newStore = super.update(id, newStore);
       em.getTransaction().commit();

       return newStore;
   }
   ```
2. *update(String, T)*: a generic method for making an update. Checks that ids match and performs merge operation.

   ```
   public T update(String id, T newObj) {
      if (newObj == null) {
       throw new EmptyPayloadException(type.getSimpleName());
      }


      Type superclass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();

      if (superclass instanceof Class) {
          superclass = ((Class) superclass).getGenericSuperclass();
      }

      Class<T> type = (Class<T>) (((ParameterizedType) superclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);

      T obj = em.find(type, id);

      if (!newObj.getId().equals(obj.getId())) {
          throw new IdMismatchException(id, newObj.getId());
      }

      return em.merge(newObj);
   }
   ```

The problem is that this call: `T obj = em.find(type, id);` triggers an update of store object in the database which means that we get OptimisticLockException when triggering `merge` (because versions are now different).

Why is this happening? What would be the correct way to achieve this?

I kind of don't want to copy properties from `newStore` to `existingStore` and use `existingStore` for merge - which would, I think, solve the optimistic lock problem.

This code is not running on an application server and I am not using JTA.

**EDIT**:
If I detach existingStore before calling update, `T obj = em.find(type, id);` doesn't trigger an update of store object so this solves the problem. The question still remains though - why does it trigger it when entity is not detached?

Comment: Do you understand the concept of optimistic locking?

Comment: Yes, I understand the concept and why I am getting this error. What I don't understand is why JPA updates the version when calling get(id) which then leads into OptimistiLockException when calling merge.

Comment: What does `get(id)` look like?

Comment: It is basically a call to EntityManager find(Class<T>, Object):(http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Then why not call `em.find()` directly? Tell me about the "basically" part.

Comment: I have to find out what the Class of generic T is, after that em.find() is called.

Comment: I edited the question so that em.find() is used.

Comment: Please [enable SQL logging](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2536835/4754790) and post the generated SQL for the entire sequence of statements.

Comment: Are you sure that the update statement comes from the em.find call? Have you enabled SQL logging?

Comment: I will prepare a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your entity from code which you added but I believe that you missing some key point with optimistic locking -> `@Version` annotation on version field.
If you have this field on your entity then container should be able to do merge procedure without problems. Please take a look to
[Optimistic Locking](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking#Optimistic_Locking) also good article [don't break optimistic locking](https://dzone.com/articles/dont-break-optimistic-locking)

Comment: I am using `@Version` field, problem is that I am updating with a new object (constructed by deserializing), so I have to set `@Version` field manually.

Comment: Why don't you just deserialize the object and take it's id, do an `em.find` and then you can update the proper entity. What you are currently doing is kinda hacky..

Comment: That would be a solution, but I don't like it, because I know which fields I don't want to copy and not the other way around. So if I add a field to entity in the future, I will have to remember that I have to add that field to another part of the codebase too.