# How to display SQL query in Activiti 5.14?

Tags: java, sql, activiti

Using TaskQuery with JDK6, I was wondering how I could display the SQL query Activiti constructs before interrogating the database.

Answer (score 1):

Activiti uses hibernate for transactions, you need to change hibernate settings for displaying queries fired by the app. this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql) might help you.

Comment: Is "DEPLOYMENT_ID" used when interrogating "ACT_RU_TASK" when using Activiti API ?

Comment: I'm not sure, what do you mean by "Interrogating"?

Comment: When "Querying".

Comment: No "DEPLOYMENT_ID" is not used while querying for ACT_RU_TASK, this table represents running tasks, they are always fetched by the API based on Execution_ID_ , PROC_INST_ID_ OR PROC_DEF_ID. depends upon which one you call.

Comment: have you configured logging properly in your application? refer to Activiti's userguide - [userguide](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#loggingConfiguration)