# How to Log DDL and DML in Activiti 7

Tags: spring-data-jpa, activiti

I'm looking for help on how to log bootstrap DDL and runtime DML statements with Activiti Core 7.7.0 and Spring Boot 2.7.7. According to comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337504/how-to-display-sql-query-in-activiti-5-14), I simply need to enable hibernate SQL logging, which I've attempted to do in my application properties. Here's the "STDOUT" approach I've tried:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./data/activiti-engine
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

...and here's the "Java Logger" approach I've tried:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./data/activiti-engine
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Neither approach produces SQL statements in the console.

It's clear to me that Activiti is picking up the `datasource.url` and `ddl-auto` properties, as the file-based database contains tables, and the `ACT_PROCDEF_INFO` table has rows for each BPMN file I've stored in `src/main/resources/processes`.  I just don't see the SQL statements that are producing all this work.

I should point out that I've declared neither a logback nor a log4j configuration file, so I'm seeing the default logging levels printed to the console. Plenty of log output appears in the console, but no SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activiti does not appear to use Hibernate. `mvn dependency:tree` shows no hibernate dependencies for `org.activiti:activiti-spring-boot-starter:jar:7.8.0`, but rather a dependency on `org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.5.10`. This is confirmed in the [documentation for the previous major version of Activiti](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#databaseConfiguration) (6.0.0).

[Later in that documentation](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_jpa_support), there's mention of using JPA with `org.activiti:activiti-spring-boot-starter-jpa`, but it doesn't appear that artifact has moved forward into 7.x. [Maven central's](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.activiti/activiti-spring-boot-starter-jpa) latest versions are either 6.0.0 or 5.23.0, and the [Alfresco Nexus](https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/) does not have any versions of this artifact.