# The count value is assigned as 9 though only one record is updated in the database?

Tags: java, hibernate

I used the count to count the rows that are updated. when I run the following code in my program. count becomes 9 though only one record is updated in the database (oracle 11)

```
Query updateMyQuery = em.createNativeQuery("Query");
        updateMyQuery.setParameter("empNo", empNo); 
        updateMyQuery.setParameter("date", date);
        updateMyQuery.setParameter("flag", flag );
        count = updateMyQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Query is working I checked in the database.

Thanks

Comment: *I tried to count the number of queries that are updated...* You mean the number of rows? Either way, there's not enough info to identify the problem. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: yes, I mean the number of rows updated.

Comment: Please [turn on Hibernate SQL logging/trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql), run the statement, pick generated SQL together with bind values from the log and append them to the question.