# Logback logger to show Hibernate SQL has to be in caps

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, logback

I have a Spring Boot application with the following setting in `logback-spring.xml`

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.sql" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</logger>
```

But this doesn't log the generated SQL unless I change `sql` to uppercase like this

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</logger>
```

which then produces log statements like this

```
...org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(disabled0_.user)
```

Also worth noting is that IntelliJ doesn't link to anything when I hover over `SQL` in the logger name. It links to the package when hovering over`org.hibernate` but stops at `SQL`. But it does link to other more specific classes like this one

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder" level="TRACE" additivity="false" >
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</logger>
```

in that one, hovering over `BasicBinder` does link to the class, and results in statements like

```
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR]
```

Why does `SQL` have to be uppercase to work?

I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.10.RELEASE`

Comment: SQL has to be in uppercase, because the logger name is case-sensitive.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2536835/274350

IntelliJ can't link to the class, because it's not actually a class, just the name of the Hibernate logger.  By convention, logger names are the class name, but that's not a requirement, they can be any string.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. I would consider this an answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL has to be in uppercase, because the logger name is case-sensitive. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2536835/274350).

IntelliJ can't link to the class, because it's not actually a class, just the name of the Hibernate logger.  By convention, logger names are the class name, but that's not a requirement, they can be any string.