# How to create a MySQL log file with MySQL embedded in WildFly

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, logging, wildfly

Is there anyone working on/knowing WildFly that knows how to keep track of the operations performed on MySQL? I am new to WildFly and using WildFly 14. I am working with JPA (i am new to JPA too), using Hibernate. I would need a log file to see what happens in my MySQL database when i execute my app.

Thanks.

Comment: Your JPA provider creates a log file. Consult the docs of your chosen JPA provider.

Comment: You can set show_sql to true in hibernate config, it will tell you the queries fired by hibernate to your database. Moreover, if you want to check mysql logs then access https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-instance-server-logs.html

Comment: ok, i set that property in the persistence xml file. But in my app's log i cannot see references to queries fired by executing the app.

Comment: Finally I found what i was looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql