# Differences between JPA predicate using Entity and property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Say I have the following Entity classes:

```
@Entity public class MyEntity {
    @Id private String id;
    @ManyToOne private MyOtherEntity myOtherEntity;
}

@Entity public class MyOtherEntity {
    @Id private String id;
    @Column private String name;
}
```

Now I want to do a query to get all the `MyEntity`s linked to a certain `MyOtherEntity`, I wonder the difference between the following 3 predicates:

```
cb.equal(root.get(MyEntity_.myOtherEntity), myOtherEntity);
cb.equal(root.get(MyEntity_.myOtherEntity).get(MyOtherEntity_.id), myOtherEntity.getId());
cb.equal(root.get(MyEntity_.myOtherEntity).get(MyOtherEntity_.name), myOtherEntity.getName());
```

How would the generated SQLs look like in each case? And which one is most efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start I suggest to take the trouble and enable SQL logging in Hibernate while developing - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql). Knowing the exact statements Hibernate creates for your JPA queries is invaluable, e.g. you have a chance to spot N+1 query problems, excessive joins etc.

Having said that, in your case the statements should look like as follows:

- `cb.equal(root.get(MyEntity_.myOtherEntity), myOtherEntity)` → `SELECT ... FROM MyEntity WHERE MyEntity.myOtherEntity_id = ?`. In cases like this, Hibernate usually knows to optimize and avoid the unnecessary join.
- `cb.equal(root.get(MyEntity_.myOtherEntity).get(MyOtherEntity_.id), myOtherEntity.getId())` → Should be like above; again Hibernate should know that the `.get(MyOtherEntity_.id)` is already in the table and avoid the unnecessay join.

  I have seen Hibernate working the way I describe for the cases above. Definitely enable SQL logging to verify, there may be details for your own use case that make it behave in a different way!
- `cb.equal(root.get(MyEntity_.myOtherEntity).get(MyOtherEntity_.name), myOtherEntity.getName())` → Will definitely create a join because it cannot find `myOtherEntity.name` in the `MyEntity` table: `SELECT ... FROM MyEntity e JOIN MyOtherEntity oe ON ... WHERE oe.name = ?`

Comment: Haha, you knew exactly I was finding it hard to setup SQL logging hence asking the question. Thanks for your detailed input!

Comment: Yeah, I know the logging is a pain, but definitely worth it! Good luck :)