# Finding the name of the column in which duplicate value was inserted

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In **hibernate** for columns annotated with **@Column(unique = true)** we get an exception when trying to insert a duplicate value for that column.

```
2022-07-31 19:47:18.112 ERROR 14372 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry ' someValue' for key 'business.UK_3h6o7iww8015m4q3yffbkqtrw'
```

So from the above log, I know that **business** is the table in which I am inputting a duplicate value.

Is there a way to know in which **column** the duplicate value is getting inserted into? Since a single table can have multiple unique columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the SQL for the table creation:

```
show create table business;
```

or you can run the following query:

```
select COLUMN_NAME
from information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
where TABLE_NAME = 'business' and CONSTRAINT_NAME='UK_3h6o7iww8015m4q3yffbkqtrw'
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Davide D'Alto wrote, you can also enable SQL logging, e. g. as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538954/19657183).