# Hibernate and Postgresql - generator class in hibernate mapping file

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, orm, sequences

The ids in my postgresql database are auto-incremental (there are sequences defined in a database). When creating a hibernate mapping files I set the class generator to increment:

```
<class name="model.Names" schema="public" table="names">
    <id name="id" type="int">
      <column name="id"/>
      <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
```

However, I keep getting all kinds of errors (null pointer exceptions, org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started) so I first wanted to make sure that this is the right generator class before debugging and looking for errors elsewhere. I tried sequence (does not work at all, the increment works in some cases). The application is written in JSF 2.0.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Best Regards,
sass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **want** to use sequences, you should definitely use one of the `sequence` or `seqhilo` if you want a hi/lo algorithm generators. The problem is that *"does not work at all"* does not help at all to understand what problem you faced.

Just in case, here is a snippet for the `sequence` generator:

```
<id name="id" type="long" column="person_id">
        <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">person_id_sequence</param>
        </generator>
</id>
```

And for the `seqhilo` generator:

```
<id name="id" type="long" column="cat_id">
        <generator class="seqhilo">
                <param name="sequence">hi_value</param>
                <param name="max_lo">100</param>
        </generator>
</id>
```

If you want to investigate why it "does not work at all", I suggest to enable [logging of the generated SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values) to see what is happening.

Also note that PostgreSQL does support the `identity` generator (see [HB-875](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HB-875) and [HHH-1675](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1675)) when using SERIAL or BIGSERIAL columns.

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [5.1.4.1. Generator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator)
  - [5.1.4.2. Hi/lo algorithm](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-hilo)
  - [5.1.4.4. Identity columns and sequences](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-sequences)

Comment: Thanks, Pascal. The problem is that the only generator class that works is increment. When I tried to use the sequence, it would not add object in a database since obviously the id cannot be null which led me to the conclussion that I have to use a different generator class.