# Unit testing database with database-generated version column

Tags: database, hibernate, junit, hsqldb

I'm attempting to write some JUnit tests against a hypersonic in-memory database (HSQLDB) using the familiar Spring + Hibernate set-up. I am getting stuck on one of our entities that has a <version generated="always" /> tag. As best I can tell, Hypersonic does not support automatically populating such columns. Is there another in-memory solution that can handle such versioning? Alternatively, is there some best practice or technique for handling this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: HSQLDB supports three forms of GENERATED columns (as integer identity or as expression). Please expand your question with more details.

Comment: I believe integer versions were what I was looking for. My real issue was due to misunderstanding the '?' output Hibernate logs and thinking Hibernate was not appropriately populating my version column. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values for more information on this. Thanks!