# How to enable Hibernate's SQL logging via logging.properties?

Tags: hibernate, logging, java.util.logging

I have removed the property `hibernate.show_sql` from my EntityManager creation and want to replace it with a [logging level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2078461/390177). I am using java's logging facility.

As explained in this answer I should set the log level of **org.hibernate.SQL**.

I have tried it with my logging.properties, but it doesn't work:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
org.hibernate.level=FINE
org.hibernate.SQL.level=FINEST
org.hibernate.type.level=FINER
```

I had also tried ALL, but it makes no difference.

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you connect JConsole to the running JVM and use the MBean tab to verify that the loggers exist and they are set to the correct levels?

Comment: The ConsoleHandler had the wrong level.

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging I ended up with following configuration:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINE
org.hibernate.level=WARN
org.hibernate.SQL.level=FINE
```