# Display Hibernate SQL To Console (Spring)

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, debugging

I'm working with spring 3, hibernate 4. I'm trying to follow this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-display-generated-sql-to-console-show_sql-format_sql-and-use_sql_comments/, but my hibernate configuration is different:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">


  <!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost port 3306 with 
       username root and blank password. Change below if it's not the case -->
 <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="1234"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
     <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="format_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />
  </bean>


</beans>
```

And the properties show_sql, format_sql and use_sql_comments are not working this way. I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'show_sql' of bean class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]: Bean property 'show_sql' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Is there anyway to achieve the tutorial with the definition of the bean??

Comment: Those are Hibernate properties. You can either set them in hibernate.cfg.xml (if you have one), persistence.xml (if using JPA), or give them directly to a Spring factory bean that builds a Hibernate SessionFactory, like LocalSessionFactoryBean.

Comment: How can I do the last thing you said? I dont have hibernate.cfg.xml nor persistence.xml. Can you post an example, please?. Im still learning..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print query string in hibernate with parameter values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question because I'm following a tutorial that is not working for me, but after try @ashish chaurasia's solution, the link that you gave me has sense, because is using gerrytan's solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

show_sql not a property of org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource . You have to define it in session factory configuration.
like this

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="data" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This is the answer for my question, but @gerrytan's solution is complementary.

Answer (score 13):

The simplest approach probably is to set following logger to DEBUG:

```
org.hibernate.SQL
```

If you use log4j, find / create a log4j.properties file on your classpath root and add

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

See here for more info about log4j properties: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Comment: I'll give an upvote because it was helpful, but @ashish chaurasia's solution is the answer for my question. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: This seems to be a better answer and the accepted answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: best and simple answer

Answer (score 0):

As I'm using JEE 8 and JBoss EAP, I managed to got the SQL after adding this line:

> -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false

on the end of "VM arguments" (Server tab -> JBoss Properties -> Open lauch configuration).