# Exception using jTable and Hibernate on Paging & Sorting

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: constante non entière dans ORDER BY
  Position: 222
```

i have a mehode in my GareDAOIpml to show all the rows from the database,my methode show() is:

```
public List<Gare> show(int startIndex, int pageSize, String jtSorting) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Gare> gares = null;
    try {
        Query q = session.createQuery("from Gare ORDER BY "+jtSorting+" ");
        q.setFirstResult(startIndex);
        q.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        gares = (List<Gare>)q.list();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return gares;
}
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
        title : 'liste des gares',
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        sorting: false,

        actions : {
            listAction : 'listergare',
            updateAction: 'updategare',
            deleteAction: 'deletegare'
        },
        fields : {
            idgare : {
                title : 'identifiant de la gare',
                key : true,
                list : false,
                edit : false
            },
            usergare : {
                title : 'utilisateur de la gare',
                width : '25%',
                list : true,
                edit : true
            },
            ville : {
                title : 'ville ',
                width : '25%',
                type: 'date',
                list : true,
                edit : true
            }
        }
    });
    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load');
});
```

Comment: Assuming you are using postgres, did you set your hibernate dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect? Can you post the query? You haven't provided enough information.

Comment: ERREUR: constante non entière dans ORDER BY
  Position: 222  "Non integer constant in ORDER BY"

Comment: yes i already did it:                                                   <property name="dialect">
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
</property>                                                              
  
  
the query is : Query q = session.createQuery("from Gare ORDER BY "+jtSorting+" ");
   q.setFirstResult(startIndex);
   q.setMaxResults(pageSize);
   gares = (List<Gare>)q.list();

Answer (score 1):

Acording to David J. in [*[PostgreSQL] non-integer constant in ORDER BY: why exactly, and documentation? - Grokbase*](http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/12abpzbkv7/non-integer-constant-in-order-by-why-exactly-and-documentation), the error occurs when:

> A possible situation is that the user meant to use double-quotes to
>   specify an identifier but instead used single quotes. Since a literal
>   constant would not impact the sort order the planner should either discard
>   it silently or throw an exception. The exception is preferred since the
>   presence of a constant literal likely means whatever generated the query is
>   broken and should be fixed.

Check the **ORDER BY** clause in your query.

---

In another hand, you can enable the logging of all the generated SQL statements by Hibernate to the console. Add the next property in the Hibernate configuration file `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

```
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
```

See also *[How to print a query string with parameter values when using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values)*.

---

**UPDATE**

You need an *alias* in you HQL string:

```
session.createQuery("SELECT g FROM Gare g" + 
        (jtSorting != null ? " ORDER BY g." + jtSorting : ""));
```

See more in [*Chapter 14. HQL: The Hibernate Query Language*](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: i don't know what is the problem with the ORDER BY clause in my query:  Query q = session.createQuery("from Gare ORDER BY "+jtSorting+" ");

Comment: Thank you. i have tried it and now i have another exception:             org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: null of: ma.sc.easytrack.model.Gare [SELECT g FROM ma.sc.easytrack.model.Gare g ORDER BY g.null]

Comment: i've tried what did you suggest. Now i don't have any exception but i have a problem when i'm tring to display rows from the database with the JTable.  Any HELP !!