# Fetching SQL Queries from Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I was using Hibernate to insert/update records.  But now, instead of directly updating the database, I need to derive the sql queries that Hibernate creates/uses or its equivalent in a file, have an administrator inspect it and then run it directly on the sql editor.  Is there a way to get the insert/update queries directly via Hibernate(without using 3rd Party tools).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18553417/2182503

Comment: Thanks Tunguska.  I have already checked that out.  But I cannot run that output.  I need a way I can directly write to a file and that file can be run as is by the DBA.  I have already kept this as a backup plan and I believe I will need to create a utility that reads this file and creates an sql.  But if someone could guide me to a more direct and cleaner approach that would be great.