# JPA Log ResultSet

Tags: java, jpa, logging, resultset

Good Morning in my timezone

I am working with JPA , and i do not understand how one of the query fields is returning null.
I see the one of the object fields fullfilled with NULL.
I am logging the query , when i run it in my sqldeveloper , it retrives the expected values(different from NULL).But that particular object field is fullfilled with NULL.
How can i see(log) the resultset that the JPA uses(the result of the query) ?
I am a little desperate :(

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19299769/1356423

Comment: Thank you this is a nice solution no doubt

Comment: it is if you're using Hibernate, but then your question says nothing of the sort and there are other JPA implementations. Look in the docs of your implementation for how to get the log