# Spring boot show sql parameter binding?

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I am new to spring boot. What is the configuration setting for sql parameter binding? For example, in the following line I should be able to see values for all '?'.

```
SELECT * FROM MyFeed WHERE feedId > ? AND isHidden = false ORDER BY feedId DESC LIMIT ?
```

Currently, I have the configuration as

```
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a query string with parameter values when using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is just a hint to the underlying persistence provider e.g. Hibernate, EclipseLink etc. Without knowing what you are using it is difficult to say.

For Hibernate you can configure logging to also output the bind parameters:

- [How to display hibernate sql parameter values – Log4j](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-log4j/)

which will give you output like:

```
Hibernate: INSERT INTO transaction (A, B) 
VALUES (?, ?)
13:33:07,253 DEBUG FloatType:133 - binding '10.0' to parameter: 1
13:33:07,253 DEBUG FloatType:133 - binding '1.1' to parameter: 2
```

An alternative solution which should work across all JPA providers is to use something like log4jdbc which would give you the nicer output:

```
INSERT INTO transaction (A, B) values (10.0, 1.1);
```

See:

https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc-log4j2/

Comment: Thanks @Alan for the answer . I like your alternative solution suggested. I have not got time to check yet :). If problem persists I will get back to you.

Answer (score 66):

Add these to `application.properties` and you should see the logs in details.

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```

Answer (score 47):

For `Spring Boot 3`, as it uses `Hibernate 6`, the above solutions are not working.

Try:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind: trace
```

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74587796/2648077 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/74862954/2648077

Comment: For spring boot 3 it works ideally

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74587796/175554 worked for me.

Answer (score 23):

In the application yml add the following property.

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        type: trace
```

Add the following to print the formatted SQL in the console

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
```

Presume you are finding a student record by the id and you will be able to see the binding param as follows

> Hibernate: select student0_.id as id8_5_0_ from student student0_
> where student0_.id=?
>
> 2020-07-30 12:20:44.005 TRACE 1328 --- [nio-8083-exec-8]
> o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as
> [BIGINT] - [1]

Answer (score 17):

Add these to the property file

```
#to show sql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
#formatting
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
#printing parameter values in order
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```

Answer (score 5):

using Spring Boot 3.1.3 and Hibernate 6.2.7, the following works for me:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=trace

# Easier to read but takes more space
# spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

(last row is optional, it's only if you wish to have formatted SQL in the logs)

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse link, Add these lines in appilication.properties

```
jpa.eclipselink.showsql=true
jpa.eclipselink.logging-level=FINE
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines to your application.properties file

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=trace
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=debug
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works great for me with spring-boot-starter-parent version 3.2.1.

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl=trace
```