# What means the logging.level.org.hibernate.type option in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

```
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.SQL: debug
    org.hibernate.type: trace
```

It is part of my `application.yml` config.
And I was curios about `org.hibernate.type` option.
So, I have found the information about this.
I could only find this link. [jboss doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/configuration-logging.html)

I found this option is for tracing binding parameters by programming myself.
However, I want doc or specific explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        type: trace   #For prepared statements
```

in order to see the values of the data injected (the binding parameters) into the prepared statement.

Instead of just seeing question marks ('?'):

```
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    persons
    (age, name, id) 
values
    (?, ?, ?)
```

you can see the actual data injected in the binding parameters:

```
2022-12-07 09:30:41.889 TRACE 8004 [main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [10]
2022-12-07 09:30:41.890 TRACE 8004 [main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Tom]
2022-12-07 09:30:41.891 TRACE 8004 [main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [12]
```

This way you can see that:

```
the first  "?" will get the value of 10
the second "?" will get the value of 'Tom'
the third  "?" will get the value of 12
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/63167967/2623162 and https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-data-jpa-sql-logging/

**ANOTHER OPTION**
from https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-logging-levels is to have these in the logback.xml file (or log4j2 if you use log4j2):

```
<logger name="org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository" level="TRACE"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="TRACE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application.yml contains logger configuration. It states that all classes in package org.hibernate.SQL will have log level *debug* unless the log level is not defined more specifically, i.e. configuring log level for org.hibernate.SQL.XXX will override log level inherited from org.hibernate.SQL.

There are multiple log levels: error, warn, info, debug, trace.

- Message with level *error* has maximum importance so it will be printed always (unless you disable logging at all).
- Message with level *info* will be printed if class log level is one of *info*, *debug*, *trace*.
- Message with level *trace* has near to zero importance: it will be printed if and only if log level is set to *trace*.

The link you provided gives enough details to understand what will be logged. To check real logs you have to run your application and execute some SQL query using Hibernate.