# How to log SQL statements with query param values in Spring Boot 3/Hibernate 6

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I recently upgraded my Spring Boot app to v3.0 which required Hibernate to be upgraded to v6.1.5.Final.

I'm using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate as the JPA provider. When I run the app locally, I want to log SQL statements and the values of any parameters in those statements. To this end, I've added the following to my local configuration, as per [this blog post](https://vladmihalcea.com/log-sql-spring-boot/):

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.SQL: debug
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql: trace
```

I'm pretty sure this worked prior to the upgrade, but now only the SQL statements are logged i.e. the parameter values are missing.

Is it possible to log the query parameter values when using Spring Boot v3.0 and Hibernate v6.1.5.Final?

Comment: Try adding this to your `application.properties`  `logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=trace`

Comment: @SaifAhmad I tried it, but it also doesn't work

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Logging SQL in Spring boot 3 with Hibernate 6:

- `logging.level.sql` for SQL logging group including Hibernate SQL logger.
- `logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind` for showing the binding parameters

So this should work:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    sql: debug
    org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind: trace
```

Comment: in my case i had to set the logging.level.root to TRACE for this to work, which opened the gates for all types of TRACE level logs, how can i avoid this ? @Dirk Deyne

Comment: here's my application.yml : 

logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        orm:
          jdcb:
            bind: TRACE
        sql: DEBUG
    root: TRACE

Comment: @Abdou changing the root logging level will not change the output of the other logging levels.

Answer (score 2):

these properties also work with spring boot version 3.x.x

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=TRACE
```