# Why would "hibernate.type=trace" not work in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've been trying every variation to print the query parameters, but I can't get them to print.

I have the log level set to "trace" but it doesn't seem to print any trace level. Is there anything I should probably check?

I have these in the applications.properties

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

As seen below, the trace message wouldn't show

```
[2m2023-03-19T04:26:46.061+09:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m11145[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.SQL                       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m insert into relgroup_word (word_id, relgroup_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into relgroup_word (word_id, relgroup_id) values (?, ?)
```

My build.gradle is as below

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.kakaobank'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: What spring boot version are you using?

Comment: added my gradle file for the information

Comment: Try TRACE rather than trace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log SQL statements with query param values in Spring Boot 3/Hibernate 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74862254/how-to-log-sql-statements-with-query-param-values-in-spring-boot-3-hibernate-6)