# Object value not saving to the database through Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a Spring Boot project that uses Hibernate to interact with an Oracle database.

The `save` functionality isn't working as expected. It is just the default implementation from the Spring Data JPA framework that takes in an object and saves it to the repository. The object definition has a field called `frequencyQty` that has these definitions:

```
@Column(precision=10, scale=2)
private BigDecimal frequencyQty;

...

public BigDecimal getFrequencyQty() {
    return frequencyQty;
}

public void setFrequencyQty(BigDecimal frequencyQty) {
    this.frequencyQty = frequencyQty;
}
```

The precision of 10 and scale of 2 exactly match the definition of the database column as well.

The problem is that Hibernate is not saving this field to the database correctly. If that field in the database is `null`, then nothing ever gets saved. But if the field in the database has a value in it already, then it can save other values just fine.

For example, if the field in the database is `null` and I try to save `4`, it remains `null`. If the field in the database is `1` and I try to save `4`, then it saves `4` like expected.

I have done everything I can think of to debug why this is happening. Other fields for this object save normally, overriding `null` values if they exist, even when they're saved at the same time as `frequencyQty`. **This is an important detail**, because it means the row is getting saved to the database correctly except for this one specific field. The debugger confirms that the correct values are set in frequencyQty at the time the `save` functionality is called. I have found absolutely nothing to suggest there should be anything special about this field.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Oracle version is 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0

EDIT: When I check the SQL logs, it appears that the correct SQL is being called to set `frequencyQty`, but later some SQL is called that sets `frequencyQty` back to `null`. This definitely isn't being done manually, and now I'm just trying to figure out why this script would be running automatically.

Comment: Very strange... You can let Hibernate log exact the SQL statement in use by setting `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG`. Hope it helps. And please share the table definition with all relevant constraints. Maybe we will be able to identify the issue.

Comment: Have you turned on logging in Hibernate to see the SQL statements and values that are being used? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74862254/636009

Comment: @Mar-Z That will show the SQL statement with placeholders. You have to turn on trace logging of another package to see the values, too.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! @Mar-Z `frequencyQty` is set as `NUMBER(10, 2)` with no constraints. There is nothing that references frequencyQty in its constraint either. It's about as simple as a table column gets. @David Conrad, thanks for that direction on logging. I checked, and it is indeed getting saved to the database as the number it's supposed to be according to the logs, but it is still `null` in the database after the save is performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem came from. I still don't quite understand why it is a problem at all, but I at least found out what fixed it.

Basically, the API endpoint that was called to save `frequencyQty` was receiving a JSON node that mapped to the object containing the `frequencyQty` field. In the code, I convert the JSON node into the object, set `frequencyQty`, and save it to the database. For some reason, after the code is finished running, there is something that automatically calls for the database to save the *old* value that was passed into the API endpoint through that JSON node, which held the `frequencyQty` as `null`. I still don't understand why that was happening automatically, but once I traced it back to that, I just changed the logic for what was sent to the API.

I have spent 20+ hours trying to figure out this bug. I am still confused as to why it exists, but for now, I'm accepting the fix and moving on with my life.

EDIT 2/2/2024:

This problem cropped up again two months later, and I finally figured out the problem. I was calling two endpoints - one that updated and saved the object, and one that saved the object as it was. The second endpoint was running last, which meant it was overriding all the changes from the first endpoint. I feel dumb but mostly relieved to finally have an answer.