How to show sql query of Hibernate 3 criteria in IntelliJ debugger
I am working on a legacy project which does not have any specific project structure like in maven or gradle. We use ant to build the project and add dependencies like we add in a simple java project. It uses old version of Hibernate. I couldn't find any application.properties or spring configs. I am trying to debug a complex criteria using JSR45 remote debugging and it is showing criteria as object instead of SQL query. That project has struts and spring both integrated. How do I show SQL query of criteria in debugger? All other developers in company use eclipse and I am the only one using IntelliJ 2024 because I find it easy to use. In eclipse it shows sql for criteria as prepared statement but for some odd reason I am unable to configure eclipse in my system (Its crashing).

It's difficult to advise without knowing your stack (webserver, hibernate version) but you can try quick & dirty way with https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy:

Navigate to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/p6spy/p6spy, open latest version and manually download p6spy.jar
Open IDEA Project Structure > Global Libraries, press + and specify path to .jar
Right click new line in the same dialog > Add To Modules > Specify the module you are running (you can pick all if not sure)
Modify your connection URL to add p6spy. Example: jdbc:mysql://<hostname>:<port> -> jdbc:p6spy:mysql://<hostname>:<port>
Next, in your project run configuration (Tomcat or whatever) add JVM option:
-Dspy.properties=/path/to/spy.properties
Once run, by default, a file called spy.log will be created in the current working directory with SQL queries and parameters.

This was tested on hibernate 5.4, java 11 and Tomcat 9. p6spy documentation contains examples for other webservers.

Thanks but that doing same as hibernate_show_sql does. I wanted to see query in the debugger.

Great it worked for you! One advantage of p6spy is that it will show full queries with substituted parameters: I.e. SELECT ... WHERE id = 1 instead of SELECT ... WHERE id = ?. But if you have spring 3+ there are even simpler methods https://stackoverflow.com/a/74862954/5479823
