# Criteria API I consider what is the better usage pattern?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, entity, criteria-api

I have @ManyToMany or @OneToMany associations on entity and I'm considering what will be the better use case:

1. using **iterate** for each **object in objects** and do **criteriaBuilder.isMember(object, collection)**
2. using **root.join(collection)** and than **joinedRoot.in(objects)**

Here code example:

```
 List<Predicate> orPredicates = new ArrayList<>();

 for(Industry industry : industries) {
    orPredicates.add( criteriaBuilder.isMember(industry, provider.get(Provider_.industries)) );
 }

 predicates.add( criteriaBuilder.or(orPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[] { })) );
```

and the second possible solution

```
 Join<Provider, Industry> industryRoot = provider.join(Provider_.industries)
 industryRoot.in(industries); 
 // here i need also to add .distinct(true) on select
```

I consider whether .isMember() function is making dome join with associated entity through collection attribute?

Comment: Have you tried both with sql statement logging enabled in your application?

Comment: no i haven't ;/
do you think I should compare generated SQL queries?

Comment: Yes, because it may turn out that Hibernate is generating identical or similar SQL from either query. It is worth inspecting the sql if you are finding the query is turning out to be expensive. (Or if you are just worried that it might not scale). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values