# The column "ID" cannot be null with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I created the entity patient with a column `ID` which is the primary key of the table `PATIENT`. While inserting a new `Patient` object, I get the following exception:

```
 WARN: SQL Error: -20001, SQLState: 23502
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
 The column "ID" cannot be null.
```

This is the code creating the `Patient` object:

```
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Patient patient = new Patient(1L, null, "John", "Kennedy", 12, "USA", "Wall Street");

    session.save(patient);
```

The value id of the `Patient` object is 1.

I am using struts with Tomcat 6 and Derby 10.9.1.0 and Hibernate 4.

Any help

Comment: Try to post the Patient class and table

Comment: If `ID` column is `Primary key` or part of it or  `Foreign key` cannot be null.

Comment: paste your Patient Entity Code. Which database you are using?

Comment: Please provide your mapping or `Patient` class with annotations.

Answer (score -2):

are you using Hibernate ID generation ? ( i guess not since you are feeding the ID).
You need to output the Hibernate SQL with input parameters to get an idea what SQL Insert is being generated.
[How to print a query string with parameter values when using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values)