# Hibernate SQL parameters logging

Tags: java, hibernate, logging

**UPDATE**

[How to print a query string with parameter values when using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values) This contains answer marked as right, but it is from 2009! Hibernate logging config depends on version. This written just few lines down. I tried this and many others but they are not work for me.

If anybody can help, please ask what should I add to description. Thanks.

**END UPDATE**

The problem is I cannot set logging in manner, when all SQL parameter values are shown. Please help to do this.

I searched about that and find that I should set logging property

**org.hibernate.type** to **ALL**

I tried to set it in **log4j.properties** file:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL
```

I tried to set it in **log4j.xml**

```
   <logger name="org.hibernate.type">
       <level value="trace"/>
   </logger>
```

I know log4j reads xml config for sure, as I get errors in log if I put some wrong tags in log4j.xml.

Unfortunately this not works. May be **pom.xml** file broken. All I was able to get - SQL commands written to console, but only with hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

If I set this org.hibernate.SQL property in **log4j.xml** it not works:

```
   <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL">
       <level value="debug"/>
   </logger>
```

As I found on web - logging setup for hibernate depends on its version. On my project I cannot set hibernate version, but can play with dependencies on my local workstation. Here relevant data from my pom.xml

```
    <!--hibernate -->        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate Spatial for mysql.  This will include Hibernate Spatial Core and JTS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- custom type mappings for java 8 time classes -->
    <!--hibernate -->        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.gfisystems</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- c3p0 used for postgresql connection -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- hibernate c3p0 connection pooling -->        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- logback -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print query string in Hibernate with parameter values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values)

Comment: I saw that topic and many others, but the solution posted there not works for me. I trying to understand why. Do You think I should add something to my question? Is something not clear for you?

Comment: @Pavlo You have been answered by Ishwar Lal

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced same problem. Tried many solutions but system was not showing parameters with SQL statements.

At-last I did following steps, which resolved my issue.

**Changed log4j library version from version (1.2.16) to (1.2.11) for just testing**

Added following lines in log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

And in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

**And then that problem is resolved**

**Main issue, which I analyzed is library version (1.2.16). May be, there is some other configuration on version (log4j - 1.2.16) to show parameters.**