# ID turns into "?" when executed by CrudRepository

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Group\"")
public class Group implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="admin_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private User admin;
    // .. other properties + setters and getters

}
```

-

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="admin")
    private Set<Group> ownedGroups;
   // other properties + setters and getters
}
```

This is the repository for the `Group` entity that extends `CrudRepository`:

```
public interface GroupRepository extends CrudRepository<Group, Long> {
    public Group findById(long id);
}
```

When I delete a group, all groups in the db gets deleted. why does that happen?

This is the what I see in the log (I have the same number of entries in my group table as the number of log lines)

```
Hibernate: delete from `group` where id=?
Hibernate: delete from `group` where id=?
Hibernate: delete from `group` where id=?
Hibernate: delete from `group` where id=?
Hibernate: delete from `group` where id=?
Hibernate: delete from `group` where id=?
```

I'm sure that I pass the correct id to the `.delete` method of the group repository.

Comment: But why calling `groupRepository.delete(id)` delete all the items in the table ?

Comment: Can you set show_sql in hibernate config and show log that you see when do deletion

Comment: `Hibernate: delete from `group` where id=?`
I put break point on the code and I'm sure that the passed in group id is not `null` or malformed.

Comment: do you see any delete  in sql_log ? is in correct that for example you have 1000 group records in db and after call groupRepository.delete(id) with id=1 all 999 others records are deleted also ???

Comment: Any othere delete queries in log

Comment: @sbjavateam what I see in the log is `delete from group where id=?`

Comment: Can you remove Cascade.Remove from Group entity and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following lines in your code:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="admin_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private User admin;
```

and these as well:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="admin")
private Set<Group> ownedGroups;
```

From what I see I can assume that when deleting a Group you also remove admin of that group. And because you delete the admin - you also removes all the groups that owned by the admin.

**It happens because you are using `CascadeType.REMOVE` in a wrong way**. This annotation causes a domino effect when you remove a group. You can read about Cascading in Hibernate here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqm/index.html.

I would suggest to you to remove `CascadeType.REMOVE` as it doesn't seem to fit your domain model very vell. **Usually, this type of cascading is useful when you have a strong compositional relation between your entities where child entity doesn't have any sense without its parent**. For instance Company and Address. If you remove company it doesn't make any sense to store its address in the database. Your case is an aggregation of entities rather than a composition. Your child entity (Admin) can exist without its parent entity (Group). The same applies to the User and owned groups - if you remove owner of the group it probably doesn't make sense to remove all the owned groups (e.g. because somebody may own it in the future).

Answer (score 2):

You see `Hibernate: delete from`group`where id=?` in logs because that's how hibernate logs the queries by default. If you wanna see the parameters bind to the query, increase the logging level of following package
`log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace` [here's some more info on this](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-log4j/)

As for the removing all groups issue, that's caused by

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="admin")
private Set<Group> ownedGroups;
```

and

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="admin_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private User admin;
```

When you delete group, associated user is deleted by cascade and then all associated groups by another cascade call.

It looks like the `User` entity is the parent one, as it can have many groups, while the group can belong to only a single user. And it makes sense to remove all User's Groups once it's deleted. So i'd suggest to leave `CascadeType.REMOVE` only there.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters by default are displayed as `?` by the Hibernate log

See [How to print a query string with parameter values when using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate)

Just a guess: you remove a Group, it removes its "Admin", that has all Groups that are removed as well. Try to remove `CascadeType.REMOVE` from the code. Why are you using it ?