# JPA: OneToMany relationship gets always loaded (LAZY not considered)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I have a JPA entity Rent that has 1:M relationship with the items that are rented (called "Rentable"). I want that this rentables be lazily loaded, but it seems that they are always loaded, even when I use fetch = FetchType.LAZY.
Here is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "rent")
public class Rent implements Serializable{

    ........

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "rent_rentable")
    private List <Rentable> rentables = new ArrayList <Rentable> ();
```

Here is how I load the rents:

```
 from Rent r  where r.kunde.id = 83
```

but I also get the associated rentables too. [image: Rent with its rentables loaded]

Could somebody help me, please? I want the rentables to be lazily loaded!

Thank you!

Comment: Can't say for sure, but it's possible that they're loaded because you inspect the values in the debugger. It's a bit like [the cat in that box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat). Turn on query logging and check at what point the query is executed.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thank you,  will check it

Comment: Not to mention one-to-many is lazy by default, so it's not likely to be related to configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you inspect the collection in the debugger your ORM framework (Hibernate) is forced to lazily load it from the database.

You need to turn on [SQL logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate) and you will see that your Rentables are only loaded when you either inspect it in the debugger or you call `getRentables()` on a `Rent` instance.