# How to logging Springboot JPA Pageable binding value?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Mysql Table

```
data
----------
id int(11)
keyword varchar(255)
value varchar(255)
score int(11)
```

Repository Code

```
public interface DataRepository extends CrudRepository<Data, Long> {
  Page<Data> findByKeywordOrderByScoreDesc(String keyword, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Test Code

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(1, 10);
Page<Data> datas = repository.findByKeywordOrderByScoreDesc("apple", pageable);
```

Logging Property

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Printed Log

```
o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator 47 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
org.hibernate.SQL 92 - select data0_.id as id1_0_, data0_.keyword as keyword2_0_, data0_.value as value3_0_, data0_.score as score4_0_ from data data0_ where data0_.keyword=? order by data0_.score desc limit ?, ?
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder 65 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [apple]
org.hibernate.SQL 92 - select count(data0_.id) as col_0_0_ from data data0_ where data0_.keyword=?
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder 65 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [apple]
```

Logs only show `data0_.keyword=?` binding value.
I want know `limit ?, ?` binding values. Is there proper log settings?

Comment: Did you try to add logging for the `org.hibernate.type` package with level `TRACE`? This is mentioned here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476

Comment: @g00glen00b `logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE` don't show `limit ?, ?` binding values.

Comment: have you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can set hibernate type to trace for logging binding values.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace
```

Comment: I test it, but not showing `limit ?, ?` binding values.