# Unwrap and print query to console while using CriteriaQuery in Hibernate5.x

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-4.x, hibernate-5.x

I have migrated from Hibernate 4 to Hibernate 5.2.17 and use CriteriaQuery now as opposed to the old Criteria.

While debugging, we could do the following in Hibernate4 to see how the query looks like eventually

```
String sqlOutput = allStudents.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString();

logger.debug("see query {}",sqlOutput);
```

I am still able to use the above, but I keep getting a warning that **Query.class** and **getQueryString** is deprecated. What is the alternative in Hibernate 5. I have gone through the documentation  - they mention that it is deprecated but no alternative is provided.

Alternatively, is there a way to print the criteria queries to console in JPQL or mysql format ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19299769/1356423

Comment: Thanks Alan - that looks interesting, but I want to port my existing code into Hibernate5 - hence looking for alternatives to the deprecation.