# Can I get SQL query with Placeholder values in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am using JPA with below method.

```
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sqlQuery);
    queryBuilder.fillParametersToQuery(query);
```

I want to get SQL query string with all placeholder values .

Comment: maybe duplicate?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate

Comment: FWIW The query you pass to `createQuery` is *not* SQL

Answer (score 2):

**JPA Query Parameters**

JPA Query Parameters come in two flavours

1. Positional parameter notation
2. Named parameter notation

**Positional parameters notation**:

As the name suggests, JPA query parameters are shown by numbers, the example of this type of notation will be

```
SELECT e
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.salary > ?1
```

SELECT e
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.salary > ?1
Here, ?1 is the positional parameter and 1 is its position. If you want to execute this query then you have to set the parameter value using position of parameter.

```
query.setParameter(1, salary).getResultList();
```

query.setParameter(1, salary).getResultList();
This statement sets value of JPA query parameters specified in the JPQL and executes query.

**Named Parameters Notation**

JPA Query Parameters with named parameters notation are as follows

```
SELECT e
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.name = :name
```

SELECT e
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.name = :name
Here, :name is named parameter. It will hold the value of name passed at runtime. Parameters are passed to such queries as follows

```
query.setParameter("name",employeeName);
```

query.setParameter("name",employeeName);
Here, name is the parameter name specified in query and employeeName is the variable of type String.