# Can log4jdbc be used with spring boot?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, log4jdbc

I have a Spring boot app I'm trying to add database logging to which is better than

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

log4jdbc, from

```
https://github.com/marcosemiao/log4jdbc
```

seems to be the most up to date fork around, seems to format nicely, fills in parameters and adds timing, exactly what I want.

But when I configure it as stated in the readme, changing

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coindatabase?useSSL=false
```

to

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:log4jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coindatabase?useSSL=false
```

something seems to not like my reference to mysql and seems to try to fall back to H2:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.h2.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:log4jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coindatabase?useSSL=false
  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:106)
```

Is there some easy way to make this work together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

log4jdbc for spring boot wrapper:

```
<groupId>com.integralblue</groupId>
<artifactId>log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
```

which seems to pull in the implementation from:

```
<groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
<artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1</artifactId>
```

Comment: this is really nice. 
It's a bit of a shame that the default configuration is too verbose. Luckly the documentation is really easy to read. https://github.com/candrews/log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter

Answer (score 3):

Additional info:

Don't modify the `spring.datasource.url` property in your Spring Boot application.properties file; leave the URL as previously defined to access your MYSQL instance.

Instead, after grabbing the com.integralblue maven target, simply set the logging level of choice (ex `logging.level.jdbc.sqltiming=info`) and your previously defined log4j log will have the DB stuff in it.

See [here](https://github.com/candrews/log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter/blob/master/README.md) as was well

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this library in your build.gradle:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.integralblue/log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter
compile group: 'com.integralblue', name: 'log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter', version: '2.0.0'
```

If you get the warning:
`"Loading class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary."`
you can set the correct Driver yourself via properties:

```
log4jdbc.drivers=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver  
log4jdbc.auto.load.popular.drivers=false
```

The documentation for configuration can be found on [Github](https://github.com/candrews/log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter)